# Multiply or Divide by n

Tags: code-golf, sequence, arithmetic, integer

Here's a simple challenge, so hopefully lots of languages will be able to participate.

Given a positive integer \$n\$, output \$A076039(n)\$ from the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A076039).

That is, start with \$a(1)=1\$. Then for \$n>1\$:

$$a(n)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll} n\cdot a(n-1), & \text{if } n>a(n-1)  \\ \lfloor a(n-1)/n \rfloor, & \text{otherwise.}\end{array} \\ \right. $$

#### Test cases:

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2 (2 > 1, so multiply)
3 -> 6 (3 > 2, so multiply)
4 -> 1 (4 < 6, so divide and take the integer part)
5 -> 5 
6 -> 30
17 -> 221
99 -> 12
314 -> 26
```

More test cases can be found on the OEIS page.

Per usual [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) rules, you can input and output in a generally accepted manner: 1- or 0-based indexing, output an infinite sequence, output the first \$n\$ values, output only the \$n^\text{th}\$ value, and so forth, but specify that in your answer.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes in each language wins!

Answer (score 18):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
R×:<?/
```

A monadic Link accepting a positive integer, \$n\$, which yields a positive integer, \$a(n)\$.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o8HQrG3v9////GxuaAAA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o8HQrG3v9/0f3HG5/1LTG/f//aEMdBSMdBWMdBRMdBVMdBTMdBUNzHQVLS6CYoUksAA).

#### How?

```
R×:<?/ - Link:
R      - range -> [1..n]
     / - reduce by (i.e. evaluate f(f(...f(f(f(1,2),3),4),...),n) with this f(a,b):
    ?  -   if...
   <   -   ...condition: (a) less than (b)?
 ×     -   ...then: multiply -> a×b
  :    -   ...else: integer divide -> a//b
```

---

Output the sequence up to \$a(n)\$ with:

```
R×:<?\
```

Comment: ...I think I may have overcomplicated mine a bit

Comment: Yeah, easily done but your solution is still nice IMO.

Comment: Alternatively, `R:o×ɗ/`, also 6 bytes.

Answer (score 15):

## Scratch 3.0, <s>29</s> 27 blocks/<s>234</s> 167 bytes

[image]

As SB Syntax:

```
define f(n)
if<(n)=(1)>then
add(1)to[v v
else
f((n)-(1
set[d v]to(item(length of[v v])of[v v
if<(n)>(d)>then
add((n)*(d))to[v v
else
add([floor v] of ((n)/(d)))to[v v]
end
end
when gf clicked
delete all of [v v
ask()and wait
f(answer)
```

[Try it on scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/454951272/)

I'm a little unsure of some input/output methods, so I thought I'd be safe and just make it a full program with a helper function.

Answering this allowed my account to be promoted from "new" to "standard", so that's always fun.

*-67 bytes thanks to @att*

Comment: This sounds like a really nice language - strongly, statically typed with few runtime errors; a specially designed editor; a nice way of handling parallel tasks; and great support for graphics. I totally need to learn this.

Comment: [167 bytes](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#?style=scratch3&script=define%20f%28n%0Aif%3C%28n%29%3D%281%29%3Ethen%0Aset%5Ba%20v%5Dto%281%0Aelse%0Af%28%28n%29-%281%0Aif%3C%28n%29%3E%28a%29%3Ethen%0Aset%5Ba%20v%5Dto%28%28n%29*%28a%0Aelse%0Aset%5Ba%20v%5Dto%28%5Bfloor%20v%5Dof%28%28a%29%2F%28n%0Awhen%20gf%20clicked%0Aask%28%29and%20wait%0Af%28answer%0Asay%28a)

Comment: @downvoter why?

Answer (score 14):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 221 bytes

```
,.Ajax,.Puck,.
Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Puck]
Ajax:You cat.
Scene V:.
Puck:You is the sum ofYou a cat.
Ajax:Open heart.Is I nicer you?If notYou is the quotient betweenyou I.
      If soYou is the product ofyou I.Let usScene V.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NCsIwEIRfZR6g5AF6EQ8eAoKCIIh4iOmW1p/d2mxQnz4mtYfeZme/GSYMj5Qqs765T2X20d@z9gpbm4MnpiLOG1YaURA4blCoS7nqk0R4pzN6rKeCye0DtCOE@IS0xXATOKV2AzE6cqMaG2DBvc/1X4kr24JFF/lXFO2JFVfSNxFnCNZkLMiCGkZpYh4t7f@/JUUM8yiT0g8)

Outputs the infinite list. Note however that there is no separator between the output values, so the output is somewhat difficult to read.

My best attempt at adding a separator (a null byte) comes down as

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 297 bytes

```
,.Ajax,.Puck,.Page,.
Act I:.Scene I:.
[Enter Ajax and Puck]
Ajax:You cat.
Scene V:.[Exit Puck][Enter Page]
Ajax:Speak thy.
Page:You is the sum ofYou a cat.
Scene X:.[Exit Page][Enter Puck]
Ajax:Open heart.Is I nicer you?If notYou is the quotient betweenyou I.
      If soYou is the product ofyou I.Let usScene V.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/NCsIwDIBfJQ8w@gC7iAcPBUFhIIp4qF3m5rSpa4rb09d2m2OXkJ8vX4izrxAysX2qPhNHr9sY1QNjRzPIXBQaDabkujOMHSQQlCkhsbdU5RfyoBXP6CmhfcMTMG8l5QQXFlULXA/jmXG3cbFGcP4NVKWGWunOiy4p/rrl9sGigRpVx0I6kGAaHecD@Y2swBCv/B9P3KBhuCN/EU2EQIqIOVpRtqPSx9epmuZ7ZPBufk2E8AM)

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>47</s> <s>43</s> 39 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)!!!
Saved 4 bytes thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)!!!

```python
r=i=1
while 1:r=r/i or r*i;print r;i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8g209aQqzwjMydVwdCqyLZIP1Mhv0ihSCvTuqAoM69Eocg6U9vW8P9/AA)

Prints \$\{a(n)\mid n \in  \mathbb{N}\}\$ as an infinite sequence.

Comment: Looks like you can save bytes using a list for selection: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8g209aQqzwjMydVwdCqyDa6SD9Tp0grMzY6064o1rqgKDOvRKHIOlPb1vD/fwA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @xnor Nice one - thanks! :D

Comment: `r=r/i or r*i` saves 4 bytes.

Comment: @Neil Sweet - thanks! :D

Comment: Why the downvote? Could whoever downvoted please explain and I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 11):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>43</s> 39 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to Giuseppe.

```r
for(i in 1:scan())T=T%/%i^(2*(i<T)-1);T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPwdCqODkxT0NTM8Q2RFVfNTNOw0hLI9MmRFPXUNM65L@xocl/AA)

Outputs the \$n\$th term, 1-indexed.

Initializing the sequence with \$a(0)=1\$ also works, as the formula then gives \$a(1)=1\$ as desired. The variable `T` is coerced to the integer `1`, and we apply repeatedly a more compact version of the formula:

$$a(n)=\left\lfloor \frac{a(n-1)}{n^{2\mathbb{I_{n<a(n-1)}} -1}}\right\rfloor $$

(with \$\mathbb I\$ the indicator function). This covers both cases of the original definition.

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPwdCqODkxT0NTM8RWI0RVXzUzTsNISyPTJkRT11BT0zrkv7GhyX8A)

Comment: @Giuseppe Very nice, thanks!

Comment: Nice.  I tried (what seemed to me to be) [a simpler approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215626/95126), but they all seem to end-up the same length...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen hang on, this answer has an unnecessary pair of `()` -- my bad leaving those in!

Comment: @Giuseppe - Drat!  You're right!

Answer (score 10):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 40 bytes

```hs
a#n|n>a=a*n|1>0=a`div`n
a=scanl1(#)[1..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcuxDoIwFAXQ3a94gQWsELvbfoFOjoTIjZrQWK6NRUlI/70mjGc4I@Lr6X3OKJloYbBn0vZoMDzcb@AOJt5Br6uy7nTb9nmCoxiZEC43Cd/5On/OlC6O70WoVCGNlUKpzUgVD6hPzerCttHnPw)

- Outputs infinite sequence.

Infix operator # computes next term, we use it to fold all positive integers [1..] but using scanl1 instead which gives us all steps.

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 bytes (SBCS)

```apl
{⍺>⍵:⍺×⍵⋄⌊⍵÷⍺}/⌽ö⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/9/eNujtgnVj3p3gdFWCKr9DxKxA7KsgPTh6SDR7pZHPV1AxuHtQKFa/Uc9e4Faezf/TwPqf9Tb96ir@dB640dtEx/1TQ0OcgaSIR6ewf/TDq0AKjIDAA)

A barely-golfed but safe function that outputs the nth element of the sequence.

---

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>15</s> 14 bytes (SBCS)

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @[Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m)*

```apl
(⌊⊢×⊣*∘×-)/⌽ö⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/9/eNujtgnVj3p3gdFWCKr9r/Gop@tR16LD0x91LdZ61DHj8HRdTf1HPXuByns3/08D6nnU2/eoq/nQeuNHbRMf9U0NDnIGkiEensH/0w6tACoyAwA)

Outputs the nth element of the sequence. I just realized that this won't work if \$n = a(n-1)\$ because it raises n to the power of \$n - a(n-1)\$ and multiplies that by \$a\$, although [as far as I can tell](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/9/eNujtgnVj3p3gdFWCKr9DxKxBbKsHvVNBSpQd8lPLVbIyy9RKM8vylZ/1N0ClNd41NP1qGvR4emPuhZrPeqYcXi6riZIs/6jnr1AY3s3/08Dan3U2/eoq/nQeuNHbROBhgUHOQPJEA/P4P9pCoYGQAAA), this function works until at least n=2,000,000.

```apl
(⌊⊢×⊣*∘×-)/⌽ö⍳
              ⍳  ⍝ Make a range to n
           ⌽ö   ⍝ Then reverse it and
(⌊⊢×⊣*∘×-)/      ⍝ reduce it with a train:
   ×             ⍝ Multiply
  ⊢             ⍝ a(n-1) with
    ⊣           ⍝ n
     *∘×        ⍝ to the power of the sign of
        -       ⍝ n - a(n-1)
⌊                ⍝ Floor it
```

Comment: Sorry: [-2](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/9/eNujtgnVj3p3gdFWCKr9r/Gop@tR16LD0x91LdZ61DHj8HRdTf1HPXuByns3/08D6nnU2/eoq/nQeuNHbRMf9U0NDnIGkiEensH/0w6tACoyAwA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Adám Oh, cool, that works now. Thanks again!

Comment: You should probably list `⍤` instead of `ö`, even if you use the latter as polyfill. That said, `∘` would work here too.

Comment: You're [requested a bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17363/43319) for this, but the OP was posted in 2020.

Comment: @Adám Sorry, I didn’t see that. I’ll remove the request

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3.8+](https://docs.python.org/3.8/),  <s>45</s>  39 bytes

-2 thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260) (`while print(...)!=0:` → `while[print(...)]:`)
-4 thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil) (`[a*n,a//n][a>n]` → `a//n or a*n`)

```python
a=n=1
while[print(a:=a//n or a*n)]:n+=1
```

A full program which prints \$a(n)\$ for all natural numbers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9E2z9aQqzwjMyc1uqAoM69EI9HKNlFfP08hv0ghUStPM9YqT9vW8P9/AA)**

---

As a recursive function, 49:

```python
f=lambda v,n=1,a=1:a*(v<n)or f(v,n+1,a//n or a*n)
```

Comment: 43: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9E2z9aQqzwjMyc1uqAoM69EI9HKNjpRK08nUV8/LzY60S4vVjPWKk/b1vD/fwA "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: `a:=a//n or a*n` saves 4 bytes.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong. So `while`-loop only functions, if `print()`-function gives an output other than `0`. `n+=1` increases `n` with every iteration. `a:=[a*n,a//n][a>n]`: define an `a` where it should be `a*n` how ever if `a>n` then it is `a//n`. Is it correct? Secondly is it the only way to define a partial function via `a:=[ ]` ? And last when I change `a<n` it prints always `0`. Why does not the loop break?

Comment: @oakca print always returns None, so the !=0 is to make the loop run forever. a:= is inline-assignment, not a function. You are right about what a is assigned to. The loop does not break because it is not meant to - it is supposed to be an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks @xnor I think you may have given me the same golf before >.<

Comment: Thanks @Neil, that's much better.

Answer (score 8):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 82 bytes

```forth
: f 2dup 2dup > if * else swap / then dup . swap drop swap 1+ swap recurse ;
1 1 f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKRillBZACDuFzDQFLYXUnOJUheLyxAIFfYWSjNQ8BZCcHkQkpSi/AMIy1IbQRanJpUVADdZchgqGCmn//wMA)

Outputs an infinite sequence, separated by spaces.

Comment: Nice, was hoping to see a Forth answer on this challenge!

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-Minteger` `-061`, <s>36</s>, 27 bytes

-9 bytes thanks to @Abigail and @Sisyphus.

outputs an infinite sequence

```perl
say$/while$/=$//++$i||$/*$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJFvzwjMydVRd9WRV9fW1sls6ZGRV9LJfP//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9M/NKUtNTi4AsUz0Dw/@6BmaGAA)

Comment: If you add a `-061` switch, you can replace `$_` with `$/` and skip the initial assignment, for 32 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJFvzwjMydVRd9WW1sl005F315FX0sl00pFX18l8///f/kFJZn5ecX/dX0z80pS01OLgCxTPQPD/7oGZoYA)

Comment: I don't know Perl but this seems to work for 31: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tbQujixUqE8IzMnFchTidfX1lbJrKlRiddSyfz//19@QUlmfl7xf13fzLyS1PTUIiDLVM/AEAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Sisyphus, correct i didn't have much time to golf posted quickly yesterday, and today i can see many other perl 5 answers, don't understand downvote

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul I don't understand the downvote either. Have an upvote to compensate =)

Comment: A bunch of the Perl answers to this challenge received a single downvote, no clue why. Only Perl answers were downvoted, although not all of them, oddly.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 41 bytes

```r
for(m in 1:scan())T=`if`(m>T,T*m,T%/%m);T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc3RCsIgFIDh@/MUB2KgIYQUhRvrKbzfxClJU4e6IKJnt26CIHqA//tTrTYm4tEF5G3WKhBKZT86OxJ/lkxuPZPNrvG0k1UIgA1OxrpgUGVUaNegi4sBS0R9MfqKxeSCWmWTW0ieSAp@nYtb5vsQ0zC5m5tM/8lIoA/4@od/a3gCZLW8FaIJb4@Mn5gQbM8PlP36tL4A)

Forced myself not to look at [Robin Ryder's R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215618/95126) before having a go at this.  Happily we came up with different approaches to each other, although <s>both seem (so far) to be exactly the same length in bytes</s> sadly for me his one is now 2 bytes shorter...

Answer (score 7):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 35 bytes

Takes a 1-based starting index and returns the nth sequence value.

```c
f(i,j){i=i?i>(j=f(i-1))?j*i:j/i:1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BDoIwFET3/xQ/GExrQK2gBip4ETektfgJFgOoC8LVrdXdzLyXjIprpZwzjKKGT1TQmUrWFL7HgvNzs6K82VAu5OwWZFX71Fc8DaOmbn0rAciOeK/IsldHmuMEiL@JJPhkup5JHFRlDQtCHUS4JF5uJfcM8dF78w@wKDHUF@sFitBfcy5hdgJ2kEAKeziAOEKWQSLSjzJtVQ8ufn8B)

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>38</s>  35 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Neil*

Returns the \$n\$-th term, 1-indexed.

```javascript
f=(n,k=i=1n)=>i++<n?f(n,k/i||k*i):k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzLDoIwEADvfMUeOHStj5AYD8LKr9AgNWvJrgHjpfTbS71NJpN5u59bx4U/35Poc8rZk5FjIKZGkB5sbSe9/6sLb1s4MN5D9roYAYKmBYGO4HYtYC1CrABGlVXn6TzrywzO1FESlraO5YJpwLZKeQc)

Comment: What's wrong with `k/i||k*i`?

Comment: @Neil The only thing that's wrong with it is that I didn't think about it. :-p Thank you.

Comment: Well, it was bound to happen eventually!

Comment: I love how the syntax highlighting just gives up and makes half of the function body orange and blue :p

Answer (score 6):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```
{_x*(1%y;y)y>x}/1+!:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qOr5CS8NQtdK6UrPSrqJW31Bb0ep/mrqhgpGCsYKJgqmCmYKhuYKlpYKxocl/AA)

Rather than using `$[y>x;y;1%y]`, indexes into the list `(1%y;y)` using the boolean condition `y>x` to save a couple bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 45 bytes

```
[ [1,b] 1 [ 2dup < [ * ] [ /i ] if ] reduce ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY4xTwJBEIX7@xVPEhoj6IIJAYytoaEhVucV4@4ctwH21tnZghB/@7letPnem8mbvGnJai/D@2G3f9uAROia0PZyIVUfjjixBD6jjN2IuVA4ckLir8zBFheFVa9RfFBsq91@g2SF1HZVdQflpPAhZk2VeUJtHj4b3GBWWK@xNM/4BsXIwcHlONR/AYMai7LASzH3aAoffRHfFgi7bBnNcKH439BnHStqTKZLh9krpu4jTDB@9Xu0YLId7JlJhh8)

Straightforward reduction. Takes 1-based index and returns the n-th term.

```
[                         ! anonymous lambda
  [1,b] 1 [ ... ] reduce  ! reduce {1..n} by the following, starting with 1:
    2dup <                !   ( an n -- an n an<n)
    [ * ] [ /i ] if       !   ( a_n+1 ) multiply if an < n, int-divide otherwise
]
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
Fμ?*`÷<¹³)ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9odXNr/23igoH/Rs68Pypgw7c8wrnCsynhuKP///9bMSwyLDMsNCw1LDYsMTcsOTksMzE0XQ)

```
F               # Fold a function over
          ḣ     # sequence from 1..input;
 μ?*`÷<¹³)      # function with 2 arguments:
  ?             # if
      <¹³       # arg 2 is smaller than arg 1
   *            # arg 1 times arg 2
    `÷          # else arg 1 integer divided by arg 2
```

Comment: Somehow there's no good way to duplicate 2 arguments..

Comment: @Razetime - yes.  I tried a lot of variations but couldn't get away from that pesky ```flip```!

Comment: ``F§|*`÷ḣ`` saves four bytes [TIO](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8b/boeU1WgmHtz/csfj////RhjpGOsY6JjqmOmY6huY6lpY6xoYmsQA). (Method idea of a logical OR taken from Neil's comment under my Python answer.)

Comment: @JonathanAllan - That's much better than mine!  You should post it as an answer yourself.

Comment: Got it down to six, so [posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215713/53748).

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-Minteger -p`, 35 bytes

```perl
map$.=$_>$.?$.*$_:$./$_,2..$_;$_=$.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgEAXAy7yvyBcFERTWCTzD0oeEULqY52@b0Vjv2ew5FfSQHTzADrKCA6SfSMgG8aDZuHxFWyr5NRdSbvGK1Zz@)

Takes `n` as input and prints the `n`<sup>`th`</sup> item in the list.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

Prints the infinite sequence.

```
λN>₁N›i÷ë*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3G4/u0dNjX6PGnZlHt5@eLXW//8A)

**Commented**:

```python
λ              # infinite list generation
               # implicitly push a(n-1) (initially 1)
 N>            # push n, since N is 0-indexed, this needs to be incremented
   ₁N›         # is a(n-1) > n-1?
      i÷       # if this is true, integer divide a(n-1) by n
        ë*     # else multiply a(n-1) and n
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 51 bytes

```forth
: f 1+ 1 tuck ?do i 2dup <= if * else / then loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxLDoIwFEXnXcUJQw01BT9BUBcDrRAJbUpZf30dnNyb3I/zMc311xXJ@YnDnDGkY/zxmTwLzXQEhheL44Rdd8uFNNuN1ftAL5tAqbToiK6gflPJj2aM9MoQVCO0wlW4CXeZKPMQ13UlMhLkPw)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f        \ start word definition
  1+       \ add 1 to n
  1 tuck   \ set up accumulator and loop parameters
  ?do      \ loop from 1 to n (if n > 1)
    i 2dup \ set up top two stack values and duplicate 
    <= if  \ if a(n-1) <= n
      *    \ multiply
    else   \ otherwise
      /    \ divide
    then   \ end if
  loop     \ end loop
;          \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 52 bytes

```java
n->{int i,a=i=1;for(;i++<n;)a=i>a?i*a:a/i;return a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU67DoJAEOz5ii3BxxkqE0@wM7GwsjQWKwJZPBdyt0diCN@Op6Fzm5nMTHamwR7XzeM5df5uqIDCoHNwRmIYIoBZdYISoAlh5YWMqjwXQi2r40z2J5ayLu0KZpJDBdnE63wgFqAVZpSlumptrGm53LNOgpLjgRa4ww1pW4q3DKjHCcLpUP7X37f0gFfYFl/EEtfXG6CtXfKbCnB5OylfqvWiumCL4bhS2HXmHafbJPm@HKNx@gA)

Note: Thanks @RedwolfPrograms for -1 Byte and @user for -10(?) bytes.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Nice first answer, definitely the shortest Java code I've seen in a while :p

Comment: Thanks! I recently have been getting into code golf and it's really fun! I think I might be able to golf this more.

Comment: I think you need to add the function header as well.

Comment: @DMiddendorf You might be able to do `i=1` in the beginning and something like `++i<=n` to save a byte, but I can't test it right now

Comment: I looked around for a while and it seems that anyone competing with java only uses the code that "completes" the problem. It would be really helpful for there to be rules that make everything just black and white. @RedwolfPrograms I'll try that!

Comment: I agree, there needs to be clearer rules on the java formatting on this website.
In all the java solutions I've seen, they either: use only a method with its header "int a(){...}", make it a lambda expression starting with "(a,b)->..." - excluding the ending semicolon, or they include the entire file, "interface E{...}", but never just flat out lines like your solution (probably because lines like these could have been right in a class description, like a field, rather than a regular body)

Comment: So, if I understand the current rules, you should also specify what exactly is the input and output, and what type (e.g. "input: one int, returns an int" or "you input one Integer object, prints it automatically"), and should be wrote out as something more like: 
```int O(int n){int i,a=i=1;for(;++i<=n;)a=i>a?i*a:a/i;return a;}```, and called with: ```new Main().O(17)```

Comment: I added the lambda function to prevent any controversies.

Comment: I think you mean something like [this](https://tio.run/##ZY4/D4JADMV3PkVH8M8ZJhNPcDNxcHI0DhWBFM9C7nokhvDZ8TRsdnkvry/tr8Ee183jOXX@bqiAwqBzcEZiGCKAOXWCEqQJZeWFjKo8F0Itq@Ns9ieWsi7tCmaTQwXZxOt8IBagFWaUpbpqbayXS9pnrJMQ5XigBe5wQ9qW4i0D6nGCMDp8/wPoW3rAK8DFF7HE9fUGaGuX/FgBLm8n5Uu1XlQX1mI4rhR2nXnH6TZJvifHaJw@), since your second snippet is a method, not a lambda. The first isn't valid, since there's no input or output. You can't input and output through variables, you need either to pass arguments to a lambda/method or read from STDIN, and return from the method or print to STDOUT.

Comment: Sorry, you are totally correct! I was just looking at the previous comments while typing. Good catch!

Comment: Very nice. I hope you enjoy your time answering challenges on the site!

Comment: Try `i++<n` for [1 less byte](https://tio.run/##ZU67DoJAEOz5ii3BxxkqE0@wM7GwsjQWKwJZPBdyt0diCN@Op6Fzm5nMTHamwR7XzeM5df5uqIDCoHNwRmIYIoBZdYISoAlh5YWMqjwXQi2r40z2J5ayLu0KZpJDBdnE63wgFqAVZpSlumptrGm53LNOgpLjgRa4ww1pW4q3DKjHCcLpUP7X37f0gFfYFl/EEtfXG6CtXfKbCnB5OylfqvWiumCL4bhS2HXmHafbJPm@HKNx@gA).

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
1’ß×:>@?$Ị?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9qZWxsef//MeKAmcOfw5c6PkA/JOG7ij//MTBSOzE3LDk5LDMxNCA7w4ck4oKsIEf/)

### How it works

```
1’ß×:>@?$Ị? - Main link f(n). Takes n on the left
          ? - If statement:
         Ị  -   If: n ≤ 1
1           -   Then: Yield 1
        $   -   Else:
 ’          -     n-1
  ß         -     f(n-1)
       ?    -     If statement:
     >@     -       If: n > f(n-1)
   ×        -       Then: n × f(n-1)
    :       -       Else: n : f(n-1)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
⟦₁{÷ℕ₁|×}ˡ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/9H8ZY@aGqsPb3/UMhXIqDk8vfb0wv//ow11jHSMdUx0THXMdAzNdSwtdYwNTWIB)

Gives the singleton list `[1]` instead of `1` for n = 1, but nothing out of the ordinary otherwise.

```
         ˡ    Reduce
⟦₁            1 .. n
  {     }     by:
   ÷          integer division
    ℕ₁        if the result is 1 or greater,
      |×      multiplication if not.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 9 bytes

```
┅⟪<₌×/?⟫⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9nYWlh///ilIXin6o84oKMw5cvP@Kfq@KKov//MQ)

Basically the same as the shorter Jelly answer. 1-indexed, prints `a(n)`, although `⊢` could be swapped with `⊣` to get the first `n` elements instead.

```
		# implicit input n
┅		# push 1...n
 ⟪      ⟫⊢	# reduce the list by the following function:
  <₌		# push an extra copy of a(i-1) and i and check if less than?
    × ?		# if true, then multiply
     /		# else integer divide
		# implicitly print top of stack
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 58 bytes

```
K`_ _
"$+"+L$`(^_+|_)(?<=(\1)+) (\1)+
_$`$1 $#3*$#2*
r`_\G
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3zshXiGeS0lFW0nbRyVBIy5euyZeU8PexlYjxlBTW1MBTHHFqySoGCqoKBtrqSgbaXEVJcTHuP//b2kJAA) No test suite because of the way the script uses history. Explanation:

```
K`_ _
```

Replace the input with a pair of 1s (in unary). The first is the loop index while the second is the output.

```
"$+"+
```

Loop `n` times.

```
L$`(^_+|_)(?<=(\1)+) (\1)+
```

Divide both the output and the loop index by the loop index, or by 1 if the division would be zero.

```
_$`$1 $#3*$#2*
```

Increment the loop index and multiply the two quotients together. This results in `output/index*index/index` or `output/1*index/1` respectively.

```
r`_\G
```

Convert the final output to decimal.

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 57 bytes

```php
function a($n){return$n?($n>$x=a($n-1))?$x*$n:$x/$n|0:1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5Ba4NAEIXv/opHGNAtW5o1TUq0RnJIaSBQwWNbyiIGe1lFN2BI8tvNji0hl@GbN@/NTFM1w2vauLo/mML@1gY6ICNObWkPrSGTum5FfcLqoxIipf6BTET9E5nzNFLxZSBbdrZDgk8PUEhWUNJRyBQyzZgWTM@36ZxpLuFwwTibsqpexlA4WpbL0f23Qo3R0G35jj1vX7elLqoA/7d1BzJsoCMETi5QFlXtNInJl51IkHb/6YBd4l5LOJHCz9Z57iOC/7be7nyJ7D372XzsYu8yXAE)

Answer (score 4):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 14 bytes

```
=1:$>Z?$Z:Z_/$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/39bQSsUuyl4lyioqXl/l/39DcwA)

### Explanation

```
=1             first term is 1
  :            mode sequence: given n, output nth term; otherwise, output indefinitely
               each term equals:

   $>Z?  :     if n > seq(n - 1)                else
       $Z                        n * seq(n - 1)
          Z_/$                                       seq(n - 1) // n
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 40 bytes

```
a@1=1;a@n_:=If[#<n,n#,⌊#/n⌋]&@a[n-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z/RwdDW0DrRIS/eytYzLVrZJk8nT1nnUU@Xsn7eo57uWDWHxOg8XcPY/wFFmXklCvoOifoO1YY6RjrGOiY6pjpmOobmOpaWOsaGJrX//wMA)

-2 bytes from @att

Comment: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z/RwdDW0DrRIS/eytYzLVrZJk8nT1nnUU@Xsn7eo57uWDWHxOg8XcPY/wFFmXklCvoOifoO1YY6RjrGOiY6pjpmOobmOpaWOsaGJrX//wMA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 66 bytes

```lisp
(λ(n)(foldl(λ(x y)((if(< y x)* quotient)y x))1(range 1(+ 1 n))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBCsIwFET3OcVQF/6vuPgoiCBeRF0Em0iw/NYQod30Yt7BK8W06FvNwMyL9vZwKS8aq3fEuRiqnQ/q4DN93qRMvm3qZso9BiYKno4Y0PMKz1ebgtPEU2WhWDQOQmsIlAuZTblH0FlBtuuc1v8RRNjgx5Jkj8MBW9kxXxkG1MWgyaMaLTYnjPaiFYrEz@L8BQ)

Answer (score 4):

## IBM/Lous Notes Formula Language, 92 bytes

```
i:=n:=1;o:=0;@While(i<=a;@Set("n";@If(i<n;@Integer(n/i);i*n));@Set("o";o:n);@Set("i";i+1));o
```

A bit lengthy and only posted to see if I can still remember how to use the language. <s>Outputs the first 98 numbers of the sequence and has a leading 0 (not sure if that matters - please comment if so)</s>.

**Edit** Updated following feedback from @Giuseppe. Still the same byte count but now takes input from editable field `a` to define the length of the output. Theoretically the formula could calculate to infinity however Notes has a restriction of 64kb on what can be calculated in a field formula (see last screenshot).

There is no TIO for Formula so here are a couple of screenshot:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cheers, looks great to me now. Have my upvote!

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 21 bytes

```
[:(]<.@*[^*@-)/1+i.@-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o600Ym30HLSi47QcdDX1DbUz9Rx0/2tyKXClJmfkK2hYp2kqaWsYmitYWioYG5po6tSBlJj9BwA)

A [J](http://jsoftware.com/) port of @user 's [APL solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215615/75681) - don't forget to upvote it!

Answer (score 4):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>11</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
1k{î`<¿*/
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@ovs*.

Outputs the \$n^{th}\$ value.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/98wu/rwugSbQ/u19IEcLiMuYy4TLlMuMy5Dcy5LSy5jQxMA)

**Explanation:**

```python
1         # Push 1
 k{       # Loop the input amount of times:
   î      #  Push the 1-based loop index
    `     #  Duplicate the top two items
     <¿   #  If the current value is smaller than the 1-based loop index: a(n-1)<n:
       *  #   Multiply the value by the 1-based loop index
          #  Else:
       /  #   Integer-divide instead
          # (after the loop, the entire stack joined together is output implicitly)
```

Comment: [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/98wu/rwukdT9hxeb3dov74WUIDLiMuYy4TLlMuMy9Ccy9KSy9jQBAA) using `┼`. And [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/98wu/rwugSbQ/u19IEcLiMuYy4TLlMuMy5Dcy5LSy5jQxMA) with `\`` and some reordering.

Comment: @ovs Oh, I was not even aware of either of those two builtins! o.Ô Thanks

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ḟ§|*÷ṫ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATAAz/9odXNr/23igoH/4biewqd8KsO34bmr////WzEsMiwzLDQsNSw2LDE3LDk5LDMxNF0)**

#### How?

```
Ḟ§|*÷ṫ - function: integer, n
     ṫ - reversed range -> [n,n-1,...,2,1]
Ḟ      - right-fold using this f(a,b):
 §     -   fork:
  |    -     v logical-OR w
    ÷  -     v: b integer-divide a
   *   -     w: a multiplied by b
```

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, 41 bytes

```scala
2.to(_)./:(1){(a,n)=>if(n>a)n*a else a/n}
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Bu9za0gGTm2z9zpFHNB4KA)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 47 bytes

-1 thanks to ceilingcat.

Displays `x` first sequence elements.

```c
p,n;a(x){for(y(n=++p);n++<x;y(p=n>p?p*n:p/n));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzBCoMwEAV/ZRGE3cbSWw/dan@klxCx5NDnIkUSgt@emtvADBOunxDqvsaZMkf8KEmx7YSFu35@oxuS6FFtgHo@3bJunBmjcyYK555JM9uIyV52wcNukNa309dHcDsLFfJ8F6Wj/gE)

Comment: Is it really allowed to define `y()` outside the code section?

Comment: @Arnauld it's a function I feed output to. I'm fairly sure that's an allowed output type.

Comment: I don't think so, otherwise all answers would never use print, here it's used twice.

Comment: @AZTECCO no C answers are interesting nowadays, especially not for such simple challenges.

Answer (score 3):

## [Hy](http://hylang.org/), 54 bytes

```
(defn f[n](or(+(= n 1))(//(f(- n 1))n)(*(f(- n 1))n)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6j8/18jJTUtTyEtOi9WI79IQ1vDViFPwVBTU0NfXyNNQxfCydPU0ELmaWr@1ygoyswrUdBIA4lwIXjGKDxDcxSukQEK18QUaBAA)

This function outputs the nth value of the sequence.

Ungolfed version:

```
(defn f [n]
  (or (+ (= n 1))
      (// (f (- n 1))
          n)
      (* (f (- n 1))
         n)))
```

Answer (score 3):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 47 bytes

Generates the sequence.

```
v0
+"
1">">v
 ).*vv
1"#"#%
"}">!`
^0=>#!
._<<,<
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoidjBcbitcIlxuMVwiPlwiPnZcbiApLip2dlxuMVwiI1wiIyVcblwifVwiPiFgXG5eMD0+IyFcbi5fPDwsPCIsInYiOjEsImkiOiIifQ==)

[image: from n=2]

The top left generates 1, 2, … and copies `"` them into `).`, `*` and `%`. The accumulator on the middle left starts with `1` and is also copied into the operators.

We have then `i >= a`, `i * a` and `a % i`. Based on the conditional, either `i * a` or `i % a` gets picked by taking `!` it 0 or 1 times. For this we need to negate the boolean `0=` for `i * a` and need a lot of crossings `#` to navigate everything into the right place.

When looping to the start, the accumulator passes floor `_.`, and gets copied into the output `"}`, before going into the next round.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs the `n`th term, 1-indexed.

```
È§Y©Y*XªzY}g
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yKdZqVkqWKp6WX1n&input=MzE0) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yKdZqVkqWKp6WX1nVQ&input=WzEgMiAzIDQgNSA2IDE3IDk5IDMxNF0tbVE)

```
È§Y©Y*XªzY}g     :Implicit input of integer U
È                :Function taking an integer X & iteration counter Y as input
 §Y              :  X<=Y?
   ©             :  Logical AND with
    Y*X          :  Y*X
       ª         :  Logical OR with
        zY       :  X floor divided by Y
          }      :End function
           g     :Run that function U times, starting with X=1 & Y=2
```

Comment: `ÈzY ªY*X}g` seems to work?

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 51 bytes

```perl
sub a{my$n=pop;$n<=1?1:$n>($a=a($n-1))?$a*$n:$a/$n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zZNNbsIwEIX3OcUTGCmpgooTfkRCoBforrsKIVcx1Co4VmxQEWLbA/SIvUhqmyg9QpnVvGeP/NkzVrzeT5qj5njh2mTZc1XzPHBaSMN3vM6DbVWHAWy8gqJYgq7jViZOJusY/QTWj6ErHI57I9T@jPuJljZ1tFNHm1ra5M5px@1Toz/GAlNPW4qTKDmYLGHYB4d579oExWrzf7QTRzvpBmPqZDrqNJ35SUn@Rmc@9/dLOiOl/saJbVAQXbx5OIdESBUT/qmi4ols8tYG2VUGBZhfj2620KGz/e5Yq9o@zLY3GNKRxs/XNzAYzjRO2ia6F6O3vdXa1FfBH5IH16CsJN8Y@xmE3OWNPr6BXQ5nIgtVqZzIRUFXNCNyGRJWWAA5pFG0IuyByIywRyKvTfML)

```perl
sub a {
  my $n=pop;                 # n = input
  $n <= 1           ? 1      # n = 1      → 1
 :$n > ($a=a($n-1)) ? $a*$n  # n > a(n-1) → a(n-1) · n
                    : $a/$n  # n ≤ a(n-1) → ⌊a(n-1) / n⌋ in 'use integer' mode
}
```

Comment: [50](https://tio.run/##zZNNbsIwEIX3OcUTGCmpgooTfkRCoBforrsKIVcx1Co4VmxQEWLbA/SIvUhqmyg9QpnVvGdb/jwzVrzeT5qj5njh2mTZc1XzPHBaSMN3vM6DbVWHAWy8gqJYgq7jViZOJusY/QTWj6ErHI57I9T@jPuJljZ1tFNHm1ra5M5px22p0R9jgamnLcVJlBxMljDsg8O8d22CYrX5P9qJo510gzF1Mh11ms78pCR/ozOf@/clnZFS/@LENiiILt48nEMipIoJ/1RR8UQ2eWuD7CqDAsyvRzdb6NDZfnesVW0Ls@0NhnSk8fP1DQyGM42Ttonuxehtb2dt6k/BX5IH16CsJN8Y@xmE3OWNPr6BXQ5nIgtVqZzIBV3RjMhlSFhh75dDGkUrwh6IzAh7JPLaNL8)

Comment: @640KB – yes, nice.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 40 bytes

```julia
a(n)=n<1 ? 1 : n>(A=a(n-1)) ? A*n : A÷n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5NCsJADEb3PUWY1YxEMOMfWqv0KEVbqZRY7CiewAMouPIeHsCbeJGaijizCu/ly0d2x6rM6Ny2mWaT8IJgBQRz4KVOE3F9MkZU2mOR6evJbXHktSv3DC5vnC4QSq4R8nNtIoDt3iWFFtNBfSjZad25RPZSo96Pm5IimXdloAcKCq1M/A93l54k8r5cAcKEtIUJODXhumLdfRJHOW@i6PthhoQk5gcWrYchTjyMwtgYxx4mOBx4oilaG0RnM6Swk0Zopbb9AA)

Comment: `a(n)=n<1||(n>(A=a(n-1)) ? A*n : A÷n)` for -3 bytes

Comment: thx, didnt know bools are turned into 0 or 1 when used in arithmetics

Comment: if fact `1 == true` and `0 == false`. `Bool <: Integer <: Number` so they can be added

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 17 bytes

```
Ｆ…·²Ｎ≔∨∕ψι×ψιψＩＬψ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcy9CsIwEADg3ae48Q7i4lY6iS4FURFfIMYzPUivkj/I08eC47d8brbRrTb0/lkj4KQulCSVH1Y948HApN@Sr2V5cUQigmNK4hVvEc9S5c3YDAgZeMrC6Y9NjcbdPYpmPNmU8cLq84xtC8beh6Hva/gB) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: The string `y` (`ψ`) is initialised to a single null byte.

```
Ｆ…·²Ｎ
```

Loop from `2` to `n`.

```
≔∨∕ψι×ψιψ
```

Try dividing the string into `i` pieces, but if that would result in the empty string, repeat the string `i` times intead.

```
ＩＬψ
```

Output the final length of the string.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 41 bytes

```php
<?for(;;)echo$x=!$x+$x/++$i|0?:$x*$i,'
';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxj4tv0jD2lozNTkjX6XCVlGlQlulQl9bWyWzxsDeSqVCSyVTR51L3fr//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3VTFIoz8otK4vMLUvPiSxLTbf3zAA)

Outputs the infinite sequence. A couple of PHP tricks in use, using `|0` to cast to int, and `!$x` to elegantly handle the first iteration.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü↨╖Γ¥B╢╤┴
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8117b7e29d42b6d1c1&i=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A17%0A99%0A314&m=2)

The same reduce operation as the Jelly answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>36</s> 33 bytes

```
Nest[⌊#/++n⌋/. 0->n#&,n=1,#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73y@1uCT6UU@Xsr62dt6jnm59PQUDXbs8ZTWdPFtDHeVYtf8BRZl5JdHKunZpDkBuXXByYl5dNZeBDpehDpeRDpexDpeJDpcpkGumw2VpARQwNOaq/Q8A)

0-indexed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 20 bytes

```
J1V}2hQJ=J?>NJ*NJ/JN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/38swrNYoI9DL1svezs9Ly89L38vv/39jQxMA)

1-indexed, outputs the first n values.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 65 bytes

Output the nth value:

```powershell
$r=1
1..$args[0]|%{$r=([Math]::Floor($r/$_),($r*$_))[$_-gt$r]}
$r
```

### Explanations

```powershell
$r=1                           # Initialises the result as 1
1..$args[0]|%{                 # For 1 to the argument
    $r=(                       # In an array calculate the two possible values
        [Math]::Floor($r/$_),  # Divide and floor
        ($r*$_)                # Multiply
    )[$_-gt$r]                 # The condition to decide what index to take
}                              # $true becomes 1 and $false 0
$r                             # Returns the result
```

Does anyone know how to make the `[Math]::Floor` shorter?

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SZlv9X6XI1pDLUE9PJbEovTjaILZGtRoopBHtm1iSEWtl5ZaTn1@koVKkrxKvqQOktYC0ZrRKvG56iUpRbC2XStH/Wi4uLjWVNAVDCGkOpiwtwZSxocl/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## MMIX, 132 bytes (17 instrs)

Given \$n\$, returns \$A076039(n)\$.
Given \$0\$, returns \$A076039(2^{64})\$ (or, more accurately, runs until the machine breaks, but in theory it would return that).

```
C1010000 E3000001 E3FF0001 E3020000
4A020007 320300FF 44030005 1A0000FF
FE020003 F8000004 F6010002 E3020000
1E0000FF 23FFFF01 27010101 5B01FFF6
F8010000
```

Disassembly:

```
foo SET  $1,$0          // move n to $1
    SETL $0,1           // acc = 1
    SETL $255,1         // i = 1
    SETL $2,0           // top = 0 (comes in handy later)
0H  BNZ  $2,1F          // loop: if(top) goto divide
    CMPU $3,$0,$255
    BP   $3,1F          // if(acc > i) goto divide
    MULU $0,$0,$255     // rH:acc = acc * i
    GET  $2,rH          // top = rH
    JMP  2F             // goto cont
1H  PUT  rD,$2          // rD = top
    SETL $2,0           // top = 0
    DIVU $0,$0,$255     // divide: acc:rR = rD:acc /% i
2H  ADDU $255,$255,1    // i++
    SUBU $1,$1,1        // n--
    PBNZ $1,0B          // ifprob(n) goto loop
    POP  1,0            // return(acc)
```

Note that this returns an incorrect result if the correct result is at least \$2^{64}\$. However, the computation is otherwise carried out in terms of 128-bit arithmetic, with the accumulator stored as `$2:$0` (this would break down if two divisions were to occur in a row, but that can't happen).

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
ɾ‡<[*|ḭ]R
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJvuKAoTxbKnzhuK1dUiIsIiIsIjMxNCJd)

Port of Jelly answer. That if statement takes up so much bytes tho...

### How?

```
ɾ‡<[*|ḭ]R
ɾ          # Inclusive one range of (implicit) input
        R  # Reduce by:
 ‡         # Next two elements as a lambda
  <        # Is a<b?
   [*      # If so, multiply: a*b
     |ḭ]   # Else, floor divide: a//b
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 5.5 bytes (11 nibbles)

```
=\,$?/@$$*@
```

Outputs the first n values.

```
=\              # scan from left across
  ,$            # 1..input
                # with function:
    ?           #   if
     /@$        #   right integer-divided by left
                #   is nonzero:
        $       #     return it
                #   otherwise:
         *@     #     return right multiplied by
                #     (implicitly) left
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 40 bytes

outputs an infinite sequence

```bash
for((r=1;;));{ echo $[r=++i>r?r*i:r/i];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SEOjyNbQ2lpT07paITU5I19BJbrIVls7067Ivkgr06pIPzPWuvb/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 40 + 2 (`-pl` flag) = 42 bytes

```perl
$==1;map$==$_>$=?$=*$_:$=/$_,2..$_;$_=$=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcVLDkBAEAXAfZ/jrcQn8yNj0hylY2EhwUxwfk1tqqzXHlTBbNKxlH/IBJ7BFWQEd5Dati0kQRisasiSI0@BejIDxUjO@DeXZ8vnrU3ZPw)

Comment: I think you can just count the language as "Perl 5 -pl"  for 40 bytes, like [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215610/67312). [Relevant meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/67312).

Answer (score 1):

## [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org), 41 bytes (-2 bytes thanks to Giuseppe)

```ruby
def a(n)n<2?1: n>(f=a(n-1))?n*f: f//n end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BDoIwFET3nGKCG2q@ko@goRE5iHHR0DYsyNcILoxw9kJdzbxZvOne33EyQwjWeZhMlFyLljXklvlm4wMr1crea/g8Fzix4c6EgnAilISKcCbwhVDX28bl4@hM18M@McucAK/PNCIVjd1Plv9DrDGXNIm6FQ)

Comment: I think you have an extra space between `n*f` and the second `:`. Also, `n<2` should work instead of `n==1`, so this can be 41 bytes.

Comment: Oh, my bad! I was having issues with removing the space *after* the second `:`, so I assumed it went both ways. Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 71 bytes

```
	Y =1
R	X =X + 1
	Y =Y * X GT(X,Y)	:S(O)
	Y =Y / X
O	OUTPUT =Y	:(R)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/nzNSwdaQK4gzQsE2QkFbwZALJBCpoKUQoeAeohGhE6nJaRWs4a8JFddXiODy5/QPDQkIDQHyOa00gjS5XP1c/v8HAA)

Prints the sequence forever.