# Infinitely many ℕ

Tags: code-golf, math, open-ended-function

## Background:

A sequence of infinite naturals is a sequence that contains every natural number infinitely many times.

To clarify, **every number must be printed multiple times!**

## The Challenge:

Output a sequence of infinite naturals with the shortest code.

## Rules:

1. Each number must be separated by a (finite) amount of visible, whitespace or new line characters that aren't a digit.
2. The program cannot terminate (unless you somehow wrote all numbers).
3. Any way of writing such a sequence is acceptable.

## Examples:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
...
```

`1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4...`

Notice that we write all naturals from 1 to N for all N ∈ ℕ.

Feedback and edits to the question are welcome.
Inspired by my Calculus exam.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is an interesting question, and a nice first attempt. In the future, we recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback before posting to main. There are a couple of clarifications needed here. It took me a few rereads to understand that each number has to appear *multiple* times, so I'd recommend rewording that to made it clearer. Also, I'd be surprised if this isn't a duplicate of an existing challenge, so don't be discouraged if this is closed as a duplicate (+1 if not however)

Comment: Are nested lists and/or non-natural numbers permitted?

Comment: @UnrelatedString nested lists yes, I will edit the post but non-natural numbers are not permitted.

Comment: Is it OK if the output is in random order (as long as all numbers are printed infinitely often with probability 1)?

Comment: @RobinRyder Yes

Comment: Is it acceptable if floating-point limitations are ignored? For example, if \$r\$ is a uniformly distributed random float on \$(0,1)\$, can we assume \$1/r\$ can be arbitrarily large? (it can in theory, but not in practice due to `realmin`)

Comment: @LuisMendo As long as you print integers, for example 1 + 10^-100 is not allowed

Comment: Is it allowed for our sequence to have 0's?

Comment: @xnor no, since 0 is not in the naturals

Comment: Is it allowed for some representations to include an initial zero?  So, '012' for twelve, for instance?  (I read the previous answer, so I'm not suggesting to include the number zero itself).

Comment: It would be cool to see a solution that implements Stern's diatomic series/the fusc function.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Yes

Comment: does this need to correctly output arbitrarily/infinitely large values of _n_? As in, greater than platform integer size?

Comment: @640KB No but you must do it at least in theory (obviously it is impossible since we have finite memory)

Comment: [Relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/328821/222802)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Arm Thumb (with libc calls), 34 bytes

Raw machine code

`f7ff fffe` is for libc calls which haven't been linked yet.

Needs to be loaded at an address that is **not** a multiple of 4, due to alignment requirements. Yes, it is counterintuitive, but it will make sense later.

```
2400 a707 3401 2501 0038 0029 f7ff fffe
3501 42a5 d9f8 200a f7ff fffe e7f2 7525
0020
```

Uncommented Assembly

```armasm
        .thumb
        .globl main
        .thumb_func
main:
        movs    r4, #0
        adr     r7, str
.Lloop1:
        adds    r4, #1
        movs    r5, #1
.Lloop2:
        movs    r0, r7
        movs    r1, r5
        bl      printf
        adds    r5, #1
        cmp     r5, r4
        bls     .Lloop2
.Lloop2_end:
        movs    r0, #'\n'
        bl      putchar
        b       .Lloop1
str:
        .asciz "%u "
```

#### Explanation

Equivalent C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main(void)
{
    uint32_t N = 0;
    for (;;) {
        ++N;
        for (uint32_t num = 1; num <= N; num++) {
            printf("%u ", num);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    // Unreachable
}
```

Since we are never returning from `main`, I say, "to hell with calling convention" and just overwrite the callee-saved registers with our local variables. They won't know the difference.

Specifically, I want r4 to be N (it is incremented before using), and r7 to be our printf string.

Unfortunately, we have an odd number of instructions, and `adr` can only load addresses that are 4 byte aligned, so we need to make `main` *not* be 4-byte aligned so the string *is* 4-byte aligned.

```armasm
main:
        movs    r4, #0
        adr     r7, str
```

Begin printing the natural numbers. Increment N and start counting ℕ in r5.

```armasm
.Lloop1:
        adds    r4, #1
        movs    r5, #1
```

`printf("%u ", ℕ)`

```armasm
.Lloop2:
        movs    r0, r7
        movs    r1, r5
        bl      printf
```

Increment ℕ and loop while it is less than or equal to N.

```armasm
        adds    r5, #1
        cmp     r5, r4
        bls     .Lloop2
```

After the second loop: `putchar('\n')`

```armasm
.Lloop2_end:
        movs    r0, #'\n'
        bl      putchar
```

Jump back to the outer loop to increment N.

```armasm
        b       .Lloop1
```

The printf string. This must be 4-byte aligned for `adr`, which we do with how we load `main`.

```armasm
str:
        .asciz "%u "
```

Answer (score 26):

## [Scratch 3.0](https://scratch.mit.edu), <s>13</s> 20 blocks/<s>121</s> 70 bytes

[image]

As SB Syntax:

```
define(n)(i
say(i
((n)+<(i)=(n)>)((1)+((i)*<(i)<(n
```

This says each term in the sequence. A delay can be added so that the numbers don't rapidly fire.

I have never seen scratch so abused. You call the *empty name* function with *empty parameters*. My goodness. Whatever saves bytes!

*-51 thanks to @att*

[Try it on Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/456839468/)

### Explained

The main idea behind this program is that each "run" of natural numbers is printed until the value being printed is equal to the highest number of that run.

The first two lines of the function are pretty straightforward...define a function with parameters `n` (the upper limit of the current run of numbers) and `i` (the current number for printing), then output the value of `i`.

Then, we get to the fun part - the function call. The expression `n + (i = n)` determines if we need to move onto the next `n`: if `i` hasn't reached the upper limit, the expression evaluates as `n`. Otherwise, the expression is `n + 1`, giving us the next upper limit.

The expression `1 + (i * (i < n))` determines the next value of i. To properly understand this, consider the two different results `i < n` can evaluate to: if `i` is equal to `n` (that is, we have reached the upper limit of the current run and we need to consequently restart at 1), this will result in `(1 + (i * 0))`, which will always equal 1. However, if `i` is less than `n`, the expression will equal `(1 + (i * 1)) = (1 + i)` , which just happens to be the next value to print. Because there is no checks to see if execution should be halted, this goes on forever.

Comment: My favorite so far

Comment: [74 bytes](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#?script=define%20f%28n%29%28i%0Asay%28i%0Af%28%28n%29%2B%3C%28i%29%3D%28n%29%3E%29%28%281%29%2B%28%28i%29*%3C%28i%29%3C%28n%0Awhen%20gf%20clicked%0Af%28%29%28), but more blocks.

Comment: [70](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#?script=define%28n%29%28i%0Asay%28i%0A%28%28n%29%2B%3C%28i%29%3D%28n%29%3E%29%28%281%29%2B%28%28i%29*%3C%28i%29%3C%28n%0Awhen%20gf%20clicked%0A%28%29%28)

Comment: How soon is soonish?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing soon enough

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing in other words, as soon as I understand what it's doing myself

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing is this soon enough?

Comment: As pure function submissions are acceptable and custom blocks are basically scratch's functions, I don't think you need the when flag clicked block.

Answer (score 19):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
ḣN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@GOxX7//wMA)

First Husk answer! Also uses the sequence in the question

### How it works

```
ḣN - Main program
 N - The infinite list [1, 2, 3, ...]
ḣ  - Prefixes; [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], ...]
```

Comment: nice answer, gamer! Welcome to husk.

Comment: This is 2 characters but **4 bytes**: `printf 'ḣN' |hd` gives `00000000  e1 b8 a3 4e  |...N|`

Comment: @AdamKatz If encoded as UTF8, then yes. However, Husk (along with a lot of other golfing languages, such as 05AB1E and Jelly) uses a [custom codepage](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki/Codepage) to encode it's programs. As bytes, this is `DD 4E`, but the code page is used to make it look nicer

Comment:  whoa, that's neat

Answer (score 15):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
∞L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8n/9llYc3HN6r8x8A) The footer formats the output like the example from the post.

`∞` pushes a list of all natural numbers, `L` takes the range `[1 .. n]` for each number.

Answer (score 13):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>26</s> <s>25</s> 24 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Dominic van Essen

```r
repeat cat(rpois(9,9)+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyi1IDWxRCE5sUSjqCA/s1jDUsdSU9tQ8/9/AA)

Outputs a random infinite sequence of integers, drawn from the \$Poisson(9)\$ distribution (+1 to avoid outputting any 0s). They are output in batches of 9 at a time, for more "efficiency". Any positive value of the mean would work; using a mean of 9 maximizes the variance for 1-character numbers.

All numbers appear infinitely often in the sense that  for any integer \$k\$, the expected number of occurences of \$k\$ in the first \$n\$ realizations goes to \$\infty\$ as \$n\to\infty\$:

$$E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{I}_{X_i=k}\right]\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty.$$

The calls to `cat` mean that there integers within one batch of 9 are separated by spaces, but there is no separator between batches. The vast majority of 3- and 4-digit numbers in the output are due to this artefact, but there is a theoretical guarantee that such numbers (and larger numbers) will be output eventually, at least if we assume that the underlying random number generator is perfect.

---

For a larger variance, we can follow Giuseppe's suggestion for the same byte count:

```r
repeat cat(1%/%runif(9))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyi1IDWxRCE5sUTDUFVftag0LzNNw1JT8/9/AA)

This induces more `1`s and more large numbers (including some very large numbers thanks to the `cat` artefact). Again, number of occurrences of any integer goes to infinity when the size of the output goes to infinity.

---

Two other R answers come out shorter, using deterministic methods: [Giuseppe's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215795/86301) and [Dominic van Essen's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215830/86301)

Comment: I suppose the negative binomial / geometric distributions would work as well, though the parameters don't quite lend themselves to as short an answer.

Comment: @Giuseppe Indeed, but `rgeom` would cost 1 byte as its parameter must be in \$(0,1)\$ (e.g. `rgeom(9,.5)`), and `rnbinom` would cost about 5 bytes as it requires two parameters.

Comment: The math is beyond me, but why aren't there any numbers greater than 19?

Comment: @AdamKatav They are just less likely

Comment: @AdamKatav There will be if you wait long enough. For instance about 1 in 343 numbers is a 20. In the TIO output, a browser search reveals instances of 20, 21, 22, 23 and 24, and we would get higher numbers if more output were shown.

Comment: There's also `1%/%runif(9)` which should be a bit more evenly distributed, for the same byte count. I tried all the other built-in distributions in R. I do think that `%/%` will give some weird results but that's due to floating point precision issues, so it's nothing your answer doesn't already suffer from!

Comment: @Giuseppe Nice! I had gone through the list of distributions as well but hadn't thought of using `%/%` that way - even though you [commented](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215618/86301) with the same trick on another of my answers last week!

Comment: Both can be [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyi1IDWxRCE5sUSjqCA/s1jDUsdSU9tQ8/9/AA) using ```repeat ``` (without parentheses), but in the meantime I've found a different [23 byte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215830/95126) answer...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks! I thought I had tried that and couldn't get `repeat` to work with `cat`; I'm not sure what I had done wrong!

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 31 bytes

```python
R=1,
while 1:print R;R+=len(R),
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8jWUIerPCMzJ1XB0KqgKDOvRCHIOkjbNic1TyNIU@f/fwA)

Thanks to @Danis for saving a byte here over `R+=R[-1]+1,`. This

Prints:

```python
(1,)
(1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 2, 3)
(1, 1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    ...
```

Accumulates a list of number from 1 to n (except 1 appears twice) each time appending the last element plus one.

**32 bytes**

```python
R=[1]
for x in R:print R;R+=x+1,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8g22jCWKy2/SKFCITNPIciqoCgzr0QhyDpI27ZC21Dn/38A)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 30 bytes (conjectured)

```python
n=2
while 1:print~-2**n%n;n+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8/WiKs8IzMnVcHQqqAoM6@kTtdISytPNc86T9vW8P9/AA)

The sequence of \$2^n \bmod n\$ ([A015910](http://oeis.org/A015910)) is conjectured to take on all values \$k \geq 0\$ except \$k=1\$. I don't know if it's also conjectured that each value appears infinitely many times, but it seems consistent with [known solutions for specific values](http://oeis.org/wiki/2%5En_mod_n).

We instead compute \$(2^n-1) \bmod n\$, which makes \$0\$ rather than \$1\$ be the only missing value (if the conjecture holds).

Looking at the output, you might think that \$2\$ is never output, but it in fact [does appear](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8/WxNzAwMDM2MTSnKugKDOvRKEgv1zDSCdPJ09T1/D/fwA) first for \$n=4700063497\$ and for progressively higher values in [A050259](http://oeis.org/A050259).

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 33 bytes

```python
R=[1]
for x in R:print x;R+=x+1,1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8g22jCWKy2/SKFCITNPIciqoCgzr0ShwjpI27ZC21DH8P9/AA)

This is longer, but it's pretty nifty, printing the [ABACABA sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABACABA_pattern).

Comment: you can write `len(R)` instead of `R[-1]+1`, but then at the beginning there will be two ones

Comment: the conjecture is cool but integers 2, 4, 6, 8 seem to be missing (from my brief look)?!

Comment: @roblogic See my comments on the post about 2. The other evens should also appear in the corresponding OEIS sequences.

Comment: Side bar: Every once in a while I remember how mind-blowing it is that I can off the cuff verify your calculation for =4700063497 in about 20 seconds on my laptop. What if Gauss had access to an iPad? :)

Answer (score 10):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 17 bytes

```hs
[[1..x]|x<-[1..]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfYxvzPzraUE@vIramwkYXxIqN/Z@bmJmnYKtQUJSZV6KQ8/9fclpOYnrxf93kggIA)

Since the challenge seems to allow non-flat output, we can simply generate a list of the lists `[1],[1,2],[1,2,3,],...`,  as suggested by @AZTECCO.

**[Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 19 bytes**

```hs
l=1:do x<-l;[x+1,1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P8fW0ColX6HCRjfHOrpC21DHMPZ/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JQs7/f8lpOYnpxf91kwsKAA)

A recursively-defined infinite flat list with the [ABACABA sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABACABA_pattern) `1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,...` ([A001511](https://oeis.org/A001511)).

A same-length variant:

```hs
l=(:[1]).succ=<<0:l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P8dWwyraMFZTr7g0OdnWxsbAKud/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JQs7/f8lpOYnpxf91kwsKAA)

**20 bytes**

```hs
l=do x<-[1..];[1..x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P8c2JV@hwkY32lBPL9YaRFbE/s9NzMxTsFUoKMrMK1FQUShJzE5VMDQwUMj5/y85LScxvfi/bnJBAQA)

Counting up `1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,...`, but as a flat list.

Comment: Also [[1..x]|x<-[1..]]

Comment: Interesting, I missed that the output doesn't have to flat.

Comment: Worth mentioning

Comment: The [community concensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12945/64121) seems to be that `[[1..x]|x<-[1..]]` is a valid anonymous function, which wouldn't need the `l=`. And I don't see how `l=` makes this more valid.

Comment: worth mentioning `inits [1..]` as well. Ofc `inits` requires an import so not a very good solution

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 21 bytes

*(also near-simultaneously identified by Robin Ryder)*

```r
while(T<-T+1)cat(T:0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVI8RGN0TbUDM5sUQjxMpA8/9/AA)

Similar to the example sequence, but each sub-series is reversed, and the initial value in each subseries is represented with an initial zero (so, `03` for 3, for instance).

If you don't like the initial zeros, then look at the previous version using `show` (below), or at [Giuseppe's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215795/95126).

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>23</s> 22 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to Robin Ryder*

```r
while(T<-T+1)show(1:T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVI8RGN0TbULM4I79cw9AqRPP/fwA)

Outputs the sequence used in the example, plus an additional infinite number of copies of the number `1`.
Each number is separated by either a space " " , a newline plus bracket, "`\n[`", or a bracket plus space "`[` ".

2-bytes golfier (at time of posting, at least...) than the [other](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215795/95126) [two](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215783/95126) [R](https://www.r-project.org/) answers...

Comment: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVI8RGN0TbUDM5sUQjxMpA8/9/AA "R – Try It Online"), but some integers are prefixed with a `0`; I don't know whether that is acceptable.

Comment: @RobinRyder - Yes, I got that too, but I'm waiting for the OP to clarify if this is Ok...

Comment: If the initial `0` is ruled unacceptable, [this](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVI8RGN0TbULM4I79cw9AqRPP/fwA "R – Try It Online") works for 22 bytes; a rare use for `show`!

Comment: @RobinRyder - Super!  Thanks!  I don't think I've ever used ```show``` before...

Comment: can we replace `show` with `cat`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JDL Using `cat(1:T)` [doesn't work](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVI8RGN0TbUDM5sUTD0CpE8/9/AA) because there won't be spaces between the batches, so there won't be `1`s. The first two comments in this thread are about using `cat(T:0)`, but that adds some `0`s as prefixes, which might not be allowed.

Answer (score 7):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU Coreutils, 20

```bash
seq -fseq\ %g inf|sh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UEE3DUjGKKimK2TmpdWARAE) - Times out after 60 seconds.

Answer (score 7):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 20 bytes

```bash
seq inf|xargs -l seq
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UCEzL62mIrEovVhBN0cBKPD/PwA)

Answer (score 6):

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 20

```
:;s/(1*).*/1\1 &/p;b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f/fyrpYX8NQS1NPS98wxlBBTb/AOun//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3WLAA)

Output is in unary, as per [this meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5349/11259).

Answer (score 6):

## [Befunge](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), 5 bytes

```
>1+?.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/385Q217v/38A)

At each output, there is a 50% chance the current number will be printed and reset to 1, and a 50% chance that `2` will be printed and the current number will increase by some random odd number (following an exponential distribution). This can happen multiple times, so odd numbers can be outputted as well.

Every natural number has a nonzero probability of occurring, so it will eventually be printed infinitely many times.

#### Explanation

```
>1+?.
>      # Go east.
 1+    # Initialize a counter to 1.
   ?   # Go in a random direction.
       # If the instruction pointer goes west:
  +    # Add the top two stack elements together.
       # If there is a 2 on top, this adds it to the counter.
       # If not, this does nothing.
 1     # Create a new 1 on the top of the stack.
>      # Go east.
 1+    # Add 1 to get 2, which remains on top of the counter.
   ?   # Repeat.
       
   ?   # If the IP goes east:
    .  # Print and delete the top of the stack.
>      # Go east.
 1+    # Add 1.
       # If there was a 2 that was printed and the counter remains, the 1 gets added to it.
       # If the counter was printed instead, this creates a new 1.
   ?   # Repeat.

   ?   # If the IP goes north or south, it wraps around to the ? instruction and repeats.
```

---

## [Befunge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98), 14 bytes

```
]:.1-:0`j
]:+!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//@PtdIz1LUySMjiirXSVvz/HwA)

A determinstic solution, printing each range from 1 to `n` in descending order.

#### Explanation

```
]           # Turn right (to the south) and go to the second line.

]:+!      
]           # Turn right again (to the west).
   !        # Take the logical NOT of the secondary counter (which is now 0) to get 1.
  +         # Add the 1 to the main counter.
 :          # Duplicate the main counter to form a secondary counter.
]           # Turn right (to the north) and go to the first line.

]:.1-:0`j 
]           # Turn right (to the east).
 :          # Duplicate the secondary counter.
  .         # Print and delete the duplicate.
   1-       # Subtract 1 from the secondary counter.
     0`     # Is the secondary counter greater than 0?
       j    # If so, jump over the ] instruction and repeat the first line.
]           # If not, turn right (to the south) and go to the second line.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 27 bytes

```
   >v
1","@"}
^+^<#-1
1+<<<
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoiICAgPnZcbjFcIixcIkBcIn1cbl4rXjwjLTFcbjErPDw8IiwidiI6MSwiaSI6IiJ9)

[image]

This counts down from successive numbers.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
‘RṄß
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4yghztbDs///x8A)

I think this outputs all numbers an infinite number of times, but because it's a different output format, I'm not 100% sure

### How it works

```
‘RṄß - Main link. Left argument is initially n = 0
‘    - Increment
 R   - Range
  Ṅ  - Print
   ß - Recursively run the main link
```

For `n = 0`, `‘RṄ` outputs `[1]`. We then recurse, using `n = [1]`. `‘RṄ` then outputs `[[1, 2]]`, and we recurse again, using `n = [[1, 2]]`, which outputs `[[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]]` etc.

Comment: That was very quick (5 min)

Comment: @AdamKatav We have a lot of practice of finding quick answers :P

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```matlab
do disp(fix(1/rand)) until 0
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/JV8hJbO4QCMts0LDUL8oMS9FU1OhNK8kM0fB4P9/AA)

This outputs a sequence \$(x_k)\$ of independent, identically distributed random natural numbers. Each value \$x_k\$ is obtained as \$1/r\$ rounded towards zero, where \$r\$ has a uniform distribution on the interval \$(0,1)\$.

For a given index \$k\$, and for any \$n \in \mathbb N\$, there is a nonzero probability that \$x_k=n\$ (ignoring floating-point inaccuracies). Therefore, with probability \$1\$ every \$n\$ appears infinitely often in the sequence \$(x_k)\$.

Comment: "identically distributed random natural numbers", this is impossible, you can't have a uniform distribution over an infinite set.

Comment: @PedroA Who said uniform? :-) The distribution has the approximate form \$1/x^2\$ (which results from dividing \$1\$ by a uniform number on \$(0,1)\$), and thus larger numbers are less likely

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>25</s> 21 bytes

```
repeat T=print(T:0+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyi1IDWxRCHEtqAoM69EI8TKQNtQ8/9/AA)

Prints `2..1, 3..1, 4..1` and so forth.

Thanks to Robin Ryder for -4 bytes.

This works because `print` invisibly returns its first argument.

Comment: [2 bytes golfier](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215830/95126)...

Comment: (although yours would be [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyi1IDWxRCHEtqAoM69EI1nDTSdEU9tQ8/9/AA) using ```repeat ```)...

Comment: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyi1IDWxRCHEtqAoM69EI8TKQNtQ8/9/AA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @RobinRyder nice, thanks! I couldn't get it to work using `0:T` but didn't think of reversing it!

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 25 bytes

```
Do[Print@n,{m,∞},{n,m}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/98lPzqgKDOvxCFPpzpX51HHvFqd6jyd3NrY////AwA)

-1 byte @att

Comment: [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/98lPzqgKDOvxCFPpzpX51HHvFqd6jyd3NrY////AwA)

Comment: [24](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvpM6xqCixsi6vziW/rjpP51HHvNr///8DAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 43 bytes

```c
i;main(j){for(;;)printf("%d ",j=--j?:++i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOjcxM08jS7M6Lb9Iw9pas6AoM68kTUNJNUVBSSfLVlc3y95KWztT07r2/38A)

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 26 bytes

```javascript
for(a=b='';;)write(a+=--b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SCPRNslWXd3aWrO8KLMkVSNR21ZXN0nz/38A)

Character `-` used as a separator and the output starts with it, so I'm not really sure if this is acceptable.

Comment: While it is a great answer, I don't know if it valid. Quoting the first rule: "Each number must be separated by a (finite) amount of visible, whitespace or new line characters that aren't a digit.". The dash/minus symbol isn't a whitespace or a newline. And certainly seems to be part of the number, but isn't a digit. I think that more clarification is needed, as this is a possible game changing detail. This means that anyone could just do their loops in reverse and get some savings, without needing the whitespace. **TL;DR:** may be invalid, O.P. needs to clarify better the rules.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - "visible, whitespace or new line characters".  The "-" character is visible, so it seems Ok to me...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen My advice stands.

Answer (score 4):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), <sup>17</sup> 15 bytes

*-2 thanks to Jo King!*

```
>1\/v
:+<.+}
11
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoiPjFcXC92XG46KzwuK31cbjExIiwidiI6MSwiaSI6IiJ9)

Previous version that used a 0-stream and incremented its indices by 1. Jo's variation uses a 1-stream that adds itself to its indices, thus shortening the last row.

[image: left part]

Starting with the top left `0`, we push it to the left. `\` will push its length `1` downward, it will get incremented `+1` and then `length + 1` new 0s will be let through. So we generate `0`, `0 0`, `0 0 0`, …

[image: first 30 steps]

Those list get then dumped in a sink `]` while their indices `\.` get incremented `+1` and written to the output `}`: `1`, `1 2`, `1 2 3`, …

Comment: [15 bytes](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoiPjFcXC92XG46KzwuK31cbjExIiwidiI6MSwiaSI6IiJ9). I also attempted this on my own and ended up at [19 bytes](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoiMS8uKyZcbiB8PFwiLDxcbn0rMT5cIjEiLCJ2IjoxLCJpIjoiIn0=) through a slightly stranger method

Comment: @JoKing Thanks, that's a clever golf! Your other version is much more fun. I tried to golf it, but only got it down to [18b](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoiMS8uKyYxXG4gfDxcIj4hMlxufSsxIiwidiI6MSwiaSI6IiJ9) with `!`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate) `-a`, 14 bytes

```
(${$1+1} !1 )+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdVm0km6iUuyCpaUlaboW6zRUqlUMtQ1rFRQNFTS1IYJQuQVQGgA)

The only choice for the regex to make here is how many times to repeat the `(`...`)+` loop. The first iteration will always print `1` , because the first alternative can't match, as `$1` hasn't been defined yet.

On subsequent iterations, `${$1+1}` does math on `$1`, treating its contents as a number. It ignores the trailing space, and adds 1 to it. This then becomes the new value for `$1`, etc.

The `!` short-circuiting alternation prevents the second alternative, i.e. `1` , from being taken once it becomes possible for the first alternative, `${$1+1}` , to match.

Comment: Of interest: using `|` instead of `!` gives different output, but I think it still fits the challenge criteria.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>52</s> <s>49</s></sup> 44 bytes

Saved 5 bytes thanks to [AZTECCO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84844/aztecco)!!!

```c
f(i,j){for(j=1;printf("%d ",j--);)j=j?:++i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcFBCoAgEADAu68QIdglPXRNpLeIseFSFhZ0kL7e1kxyS0oiBNkyNtorcBj8UXO5CEw3a2PZOfTIgaex77N/ZIu5AOqm9I8AvXrkTbTG5RR3fw)

Comment: Why are you guaranteed to get `i=1` when this is compiled? I see that it occurs reliably on tio, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: [44](https://tio.run/##DcFBCoAgEADAu68QIdglPXRNpLeIseFSFhZ0kL7e1kxyS0oiBNkyNtorcBj8UXO5CEw3a2PZOfTIgaex77N/ZIu5AOqm9I8AvXrkTbTG5RR3fw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @AZTECCO Nice one - thanks! :D

Comment: @bisen2 It doesn't matter what `i` is initialised to, all the *positive* (nothing will be output until `i` is greater than `0`) numbers get output infinite number of times anyway. It just so happens that `i` initialised to `0` at the onset. Note: the answer has been changed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 4 bytes

```
⟦₁ẉ⊥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//9H8ZY@aGh/u6nzUtfT/fwA)

```
  ẉ     Print with a newline
⟦₁      the range from 1 to something,
   ⊥    then try again.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```perl
say while$_.=++$i.$"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVKhPCMzJ1UlXs9WW1slU09F6f//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 13 bytes

```
$:@,~[echo@#\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/VawcdOqiU5Mz8h2UY/5rcoFYCmkKBv8B)

Outputs `1`, `1 2`, `1 2 3 4`, `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`, etc, with every number on its own line.

- `echo@#\` Output the prefix lengths of the current list, ie, `1..n` where n is the current list length. This is done as a side effect.
- `$:@,~` Append the list to itself `,~` and call the function recursively `$:@`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 61 bytes

```java
v->{for(int i,j=2;;j++)for(i=0;++i<j;)System.out.println(i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY69CoMwFEZ3n@KOBmsoXaMunTsJXUqHNP5w05iIuRGK@OxpENfD4fuOlqssdfeNc/gYVKCM9B4eEi1sGYAnSYnqZPFAaPgQrCJ0lt@d9WHql@rpsGtggDquZbMNbsnREuBF1zchdFGwA9VXURRYacHan6d@4i4Qn5ekGpsjE3sEEGfDebqmYZhSSd5SEsfXG@QyenaEAQxcKtXPlNtgDBOJ7dke/w)

Edit: Thanks @user for shaving off a few bytes and helping me learn something today! Big thanks to @KevinCruijssen for -2 bytes.

Comment: Nice answer! [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY3BDoIwEETvfMUe21SJ8bryCV7kSDxUQLIVWtIWjGn49roS5zKTyeSN0as@mu6V5@UxUgvtqEOAqyYLKa@OOrgJmchGoIOpzvh0XiAapeQvUXVCpehiUNafEPupdEssZ8/70QqSuGWAPzlEHdl25sR8UUfeDc0dtB@ChFQAy/bv/V3Iko@Ru63Y8hc) by using newlines and rearranging the loop. I don't know if you need a proper method for this one. You could also use a [Runnable](https://tio.run/##VU45DsIwEOzzii1tmUSIdgk/oCElonBOrXHsyEckFOXtxiAaqjk0mhklV1mq/pmW2GrqoNPSe7hKMrAVAD/XBxky3KIxstUDjFAnxsvLRiYAHVR9wtE6hqiE4B9G9RGFoLNC3rx8GObKxlAtLue1YcRxTwD4375a6mHOy6wJOTjdHyDd5Pn3CMBYuWgYxyz2Yk9v).

Comment: [61 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY49C4MwFEV3f8UbDdZQukZdOncSupQOafzgpTER8yIU8benaXG7XA73Hi1XWeruHefwMqhAGek93CRa2DIAT5JSqxPFA6HhQ7CK0Fl@ddaHqV@qu8OugQHquJbNhpYAT7q@iMEtuRC6KNgvYX0WRYGVFqz9eOon7gLxeUm8sTkysUcAcUgcr2tahimp5C0lcHw8QS6jZ38zgIFLpfqZchuMYSJ1e7bHLw) by changing the `()->` to `v->` ([empty unused parameters are allowed by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12681/52210)) and putting the `int i,j=2;` inside the loop to save on the `;`.

Comment: Here's my [47 byte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215922/94107) solution. I made a new post because the method approach was different.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
Ｗ¹«Ｉ⊕ⅉＤ⸿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/788IzMnVUHDUFOhmoszoCgzr0TDObG4RMMzL7koNTc1ryQ1RSNLU1PTmovTpTS3QAPEgChTiilSAvJq////r1uWAwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Works by repeatedly printing the next number to the canvas and then dumping the entire canvas.

2 bytes for a version that prints the \$ n \$th term of a sequence:

```
ＩΣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9npXnFv//b2hkbGJqZm5hCQA) Explanation: Simply prints the digital sum of the input. Given any natural number \$ n \$, all the values of the form \$ \frac { 10 ^ n - 1 } 9 10 ^ m \$ have a digital sum of \$ n \$ for every \$ m \$, thus each natural number appears infinitely often.

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 54 bytes

```rust
(2..).for_each(|x|(1..x).for_each(|y|print!("{} ",y)))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6GpUP1fw0hPT1MvLb8oPjUxOUOjpqJGw1BPrwJZqLKmoCgzr0RRQ6m6VkFJp1JTU/N/7X8A)

Comment: Welcome to the site, nice first answer!

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 17 bytes

```ruby
loop{p *1..$.+=1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/Pyc/v6C6QEHLUE9PRU/b1rD2/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 29 bytes

```javascript
for(n=k=1;;)print(n=--n||k++)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SCPPNtvW0Npas6AoM68EyNPVzaupydbW1vz/HwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 32 bytes

```
1 [ dup bit-count . 1 + t ] loop
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcqxCoAgFEbhvaf490hwrQcIl5ZoigYzI8lSbleip7doOct3Vm04UB561bU1dkun9Tg0b3/E7Ph2l0Uky/xEciejKVRX4zKk2WxZYsSSIr6zMiF9LiBRgjHBhxBzfgE)

Loops over the positive integers and prints their bit count (the number of 1 bits, a.k.a. popcount) forever. Outputting nth term would be simply 9-bytes `bit-count`. (I checked that the function works with bigints.)

Uses the same logic as [Neil's Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215794/78410) that there are infinitely many numbers whose digit sum equals n, except that this one uses bits instead. More precisely, for any positive integer n, \$2^m(2^n-1)\$ for any non-negative integer m has exactly n bits on, so the sequence contains infinitely many n's for any n.

Comment: My first idea was in fact bitcount but I then realised the same idea worked in base 10 anyway, which was trivial in Charcoal.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (Browser), 40 bytes

```
f=(x=1)=>setInterval(_=>alert(x,f(x+1)))
```

Not very competitive answer :(

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) + [rand crate](https://crates.io/crates/rand), 43 bytes

```
||loop{print!("{} ",rand::random::<u32>())}
```

Uses the rand crate to output random numbers, meaning every number is printed infinitely many times.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I know nothing about Rust, but when I run your code it fails with an error: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/vygxL8VWyUCJKyc/v6C6oCgzr0RRQ6m6VkFJByRlZQUi83OtrGxKjY3sNDQ1a///BwA "Rust – Try It Online")

Comment: That lines belongs into the `Cargo.toml` file, which defines the dependencies. Not sure how it works with that site

Comment: If you require the *Cargo.toml* file for your code I think you have to count the entire file. A better solution would be to use the language `Rust + rand crate` and just remove the `rand="0"`.

Comment: And we require solutions on this site to be either full program or a function. In this a closure would be the shortest: `||loop{print!("{} ",rand::random::<u32>())}`

Comment: @ovs thanks for the info, fixed the two issues you brought up

Answer (score 3):

## Zsh, <s>29</s> .. 19 bytes

Solution by @AdamKatz: [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IQUPDWls701pTMzU5I1@h2lBPTyWz9v9/AA)

```bash
for ((;++i;))seq $i
```

*<sub>19 bytes, port from bash : `s(){seq $[++n];s};s`</sub>*

*<sub>[25 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IQUPDWls701pTMzU5I1@h2lBPTyWz9v9/AA) (per @AdamKatz) : `for ((;++i;))echo {1..$i}`</sub>*

*<sub>[25 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IQUPD2jpTW1tTszijNE1BN1PBUFcl8/9/AA) : `for ((;;i++))shuf -i 1-$i`</sub>*

*<sub>[26 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IQUPD2lpTMzU5I1@h2lBPTyVaWzsztvb/fwA) (per @AdamKatz) : `for ((;;))echo {1..$[++i]}`</sub>*

*<sub>[29 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IQUMj09bQ2lpTMzU5I1@h2lBPTyU6U1s7tvb/fwA) : `for ((i=1;;))echo {1..$[i++]}`</sub>*

*<sub>I tried to use `/dev/random` for an alternative but it was a mess!</sub>*

Comment: Nice, that's fully native and without subshells! `for ((;;))echo {1..$[++i]}` saves you 3B by assuming `i` is either undefined or `0`. [Try it online](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IQUPD2lpTMzU5I1@h2lBPTyVaWzsztvb/fwA)

Comment: Not any more. Saved a byte using `shuf` from `coreutils`

Comment: cool, that gives me a way to get the native subshell-free version down to 25B as well: `for ((;++i;))echo {1..$i}` [Try it online](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IQUPDWls701pTMzU5I1@h2lBPTyWz9v9/AA)

Comment: If you don't care about white space (this has a newline delimiter, printing each number on its own line), you can do `for ((;++i;))seq $i` at 19B. [Try it online](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IQUPDWls701pTMzU5I1@h2lBPTyWz9v9/AA)

Comment: Thanks, will update this soon. Another one for 19B: `s(){seq $[++n];s};s`

Comment: [yes it is](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215935/43035) 

Answer (score 3):

## [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), 36 bytes

```
Loop
Loop,%A_Index%
Send,%A_Index%`t
```

Output is via keyboard simulation so it will print in whatever the active window is.
Numbers are separated by tabs.

```
1   1   2   1   2   3   1   2   3   4   1   2   3   4   5   1   2   3   4   5   6   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
```

---

Alternatively - and not in compliance with the challenge spec - if you prefer your numbers to be spoken rather than printed:

```
Loop
Loop,%A_Index%
ComObjCreate("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak(A_Index)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 27 bytes

```julia
f(n=1)=println.(1:n),f(n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P00jz9ZQ07agKDOvJCdPT8PQKk9TByiobagJlNP8DwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 50 bytes

```rust
||for i in(1..).flat_map(|n|1..n){print!("{} ",i)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcgxCsAgDADA3VekTgkUobP0LcWhAUFTsemkvt1649Xv1ckCOURBaulWYDhn7/xUiLDycI4cp6BXDgW79BVCrdQouqFtA@weaUwPhpG8GfMH)

I know there are a couple of rust answers already, but this one is deterministic and takes a different (and shorter) approach to the problem. explanation:

```rust
||for i in(1..).flat_map(|n|1..n){print!("{} ",i)} //anonymous function
          (1..)                                    //for evey n from 1..infinite
               .flat_map(|n|1..n)                  //map to range from 1..n and flatten
  for i in                       {print!("{} ",i)} //print with a trailing space
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 34 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @tsh*

```javascript
for(n=k=0;;)print(n=n<k?n+1:++k/k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SCPPNtvWwNpas6AoM68EyMuzybbP0za00tbO1s/W/J@mofkfAA)

Returning the n-th term would be **31 bytes**:

```javascript
n=>(m=(8*n+1)**.5-1>>1)*~m/2-~n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCoMwEEDRvaeYhYuZhGgVCgWbnMWgprToTNHSTYhXj7r6b/E//u@3YX1/f4ZlnHKwma3DxeJDsW5IqepuGudO7Uvdmp1zkBUZLNw6YHhCe1VrglgADMKbzFM1ywt7j2XkROdaxoBMqaeuSPkA)

Comment: 34 bytes: `for(n=k=0;;)print(n=n<k?n+1:++k/k)`

Comment: 29 bytes: `for(n=k=1;;)print(n=--n||k++)`

Comment: @Sisyphus I now realize that I've completely misunderstood this challenge. (I thought we were _required_ to output A002260 and nothing else.) I think you should post your version separately.

Comment: @Arnauld Ah, I see. I've posted mine then.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>12</s> 11 bytes (SBCS)

*Saved 1 byte thanks to [@ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)*

```apl
{∇1+⍴⎕←⍳⍵}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9hcGwtZHlhbG9n//974oiHMSvijbTijpXihpDijbPijbV9Mf//)

This one also uses the sequence from the question.

Comment: [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9hcGwtZHlhbG9n//974oiHMSvijbTijpXihpDijbPijbV9Mf//) by using the return value of `←`.

Comment: @ovs Thanks. I'd tried reversing and then picking the first element, which wasn't any shorter, but I hadn't thought of using rho to get the number.

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 34 bytes

```
{for(;;++i)for(j=0;j++<i;)print j}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SMPaWls7UxPEyrI1sM7S1rbJtNYsKMrMK1HIqv3/XwEA)

Comment: @AdamKatz No, `j` needs to be re-initialised for every iteration of the inner loop.

Comment: hah, good point

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 30 bytes

```php
<?for(;;)echo--$j?:$j=++$i,~_;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxj4tv0jD2lozNTkjX1dXJcveSiXLVltbJVOnLt76//9/@QUlmfl5xf91UxSKM/KLSuLzC1Lz4ksS02398wA)

The numbers are separated by a no-break space (U+00A0).

Comment: I think you can omit the `<?` part, it's required to count it when it's `<?=` because it's an alias for `echo`, but that's not the case here. We don't ask browser javascript to count the `<script>` tags after all

Comment: @Kaddath Notice that that's true for answers meant to be executed with the CLI interface (E.g.: `php -r`). For answers written for a web server and you need to write PHP, you will need the opening tags.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel yes you're right, I tend to assimilate one to the other because so far I have never seen a question here where requisites directly or indirectly makes you cannot use the CLI interface

Comment: @Kaddath Sometimes, if you want to use PHP 4.1, you can just say that the input comes from POST, GET or COOKIE and use a webserver running that version of PHP, since the keys of those variables will be available into variables (say, a cookie called "abc" will create a variable called `$abc`). This can help to save a fair bit of code, on some situations. In this case, you are required to use `<?`. In the case of `php -r`, you are required to do NOT use `<?`. If you use `php -f` (if needed), you have to use `<?` too. But yes, in this case, `php -r` is the safest option and saves 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 bytes

```
VImRJ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=VImRJ&i=)

### Explanation

```
VImRJ
VIm   map 1..infinity to
   R  range 1..i
    J join with spaces
  m   print each iteration
```

Comment: If you were a few hours earlier, I could have up voted this. Now I have to wait 24 hours. Very sad.

Answer (score 2):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 46 bytes

```
procedure f()
i:=0;|1&write(1to(i+:=1))&\z
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0zOz/v/v6AoPzk1pbQoVSFNQ5Mr08rWwLrGUK28KLMkVcOwJF8jU9vK1lBTUy2miis1LwVJeW5iZh5QhwIQQFQD9WuC1QAA)

Of course `procedure` ... `end` block makes it very verbose.

Too bad `seq()` doesn't work with bigints - otherwise I could've saved some bytes with

```
procedure f()
|1&write(1to seq())&\z
end
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 31 bytes

```
Print@Floor[Sec@n^2]~Do~{n,∞}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvxMEtJz@/KDo4NdkhL84ots4lv646T@dRx7za////AwA)

Not quite as short as the other Mathematica answer, but implements a different and more mathematically interesting sequence, namely the integer part of \$\sec^2n\$; the fact that this includes every natural number infinitely often follows from the fact that the integers are uniformly distributed modulo \$\pi\$.

Comment: [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvxOFRT1dwarJDXpzRo57uOpf8uuo8nUcd82r///8PAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, <s>47</s>  46 bytes

Thanks to @user recommended to change `true` to `1>0`.

```
a=[1];while 1>0;println(a);push!(a,last(a)+1);end
```

output:

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

## Python 3, 45 bytes

```python
a=[1]
while 1:
    print(a)
    a+=[a[-1]+1]
```

Comment: I don't know Julia, but could `true` be `0<1`?

Comment: @user yes it can, thanks

Comment: By the way, it's recommended to add a link to an online interpreter/compiler, like [this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9E22jCWqzwjMydVwdCKS6GgKDOvRCNRk0shUds2OjFa1zBW2zD2/38A). TIO can generate the Markdown for your answer for you, so it's also more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 6 bytes

```
,r1)ro
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f9fp8hQsyj//38A)

Explanation:

```
,       # Don't take implicit input from stdin
 r1     # Range from 1 to infinity
   )    # Map each value to
    ro  # Range from 1 to value
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 54 bytes

```java
A b;{b=(s,i)->{System.out.print(s+=i+++s);b.B(s,i);};}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDBjsIgEIbP9ClITxCQ6h6X1aTeNnHjwZNHKFhxtZqCbo3ps3ehrdVkzXKAzDDzzzf/TlzEaKe@m9NZ7k0Gs72wFn4JU8BbFAHrhBuya58CpnC63IhMwzSE4HI0Cs7RypWmyKGk0BdAg3kE6ihqUij5TU6RpQaPZrfV1Tp9YMezYydf75AlU0MIsZhLNm@reM3rBvAo9IMeqqdoRx08Wj@NMQYFbjlBoX/gGmEWZGIY04kn8CdJAKiYGFJdrFBM6SQeYolCe1qW4row1n18@h1zXc5QEA8loH@AUArddTxgeOp@1ySBS7fVJfRs2r6HvxZYPLzprPnrguxckJgLJFsPhm6JWqLFschn1YvWCnO/n6ca04rl2qExJh5Qho@HSjYwvJ4e05hIlm1Fmd4VMiSfFdS/ClPJTKF0tdyg2PuavJEJaTXDjbnqtOqo@QU)

Usually in lambda functions, this website doesn't include the "interface name =" part, but my answer was a declaration statement without the initialization, so I decided to include it. I couldn't find a rule about it.

My older, wrongly counted, **47 byte** solution: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZCxbsIwEEBn5ytOnhw52NCxKUhhq0TFwMRoxyaYQoISQ4NQvj21k5B2QCy27nz3/O4O4iomB/Xdni/yaFJIj6Kq4EuYHO5BgCor7JjduhQyudXlTqQaEh@ia2EULMnGlibPQEbgCsCEcYAa18/5XlRgC5AaetbITEDCvCUyMuFkcd/cKqtPrLhYdnYkSySdG0qpDOMtk2zZ1cVNi@LAk9GgO7A6iZOTHjwYYyDCzs@PwnoEBhzNnFnAOUI1E2OijxXBUTTDYyxJrn8gKUtxW5nKfny6yTNdLogH@xI0XEgoRR4cJ@evZtgA57C2e12C89LVu3/rZMXfxvqFvdqAGKYfuyXpjFZFni3qJ611GLv5nNU0qlmmLZmG1AlK//BHSUeH57/jCFPJ0r0okwchJfI/Qb0kzCUzudL1ekew2yt/ozPaMf0ZxqpnNUH7Cw)

(forced) inputs: a String with any delimiter (" "), and 1,
where Y is the class it's in, b is the name of the interface object, and B is the method in the interface being used.

Comment: Good Solution! However, I'm not sure if this would qualify because it's output must be in chronological order.
Yours: 1  1 2 1  1 2 1 3 1 2 1
Ex: 1  1 2  1 2 3

Comment: @DMiddendorf I don't think the output has to be sorted

Comment: However, since you're using stuff outside your code (`Y.b.B`), you do need to add that to your byte count, @branboyer, in which case you can just use a plain method.

Comment: @DMiddendorf I thought of that too, but "...a sequence that contains every natural number infinitely many times" doesn't necessarily need to be in order as long as it somehow gets every number, and OP's example was out of order too.

Comment: @user, Thanks for the advice, but my method will not work if I do not include all that ```Y.b.B``` because of this special thing where recursive lamba functions only work under certain conditions, which is that it needs to be static and called in this exact way, but perhaps the rule conventions allow it somehow.

Comment: I know, that's why I suggested using a method (or including the definition of `Y` in your code).

Comment: Ohh, I misread it as "don't need to add to byte count", like remove "Y.b." I'll try and fix it then.

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##lZDLbsIwEEXXyVeMsrLlMJAuG0CquqViwRf4FXAKNoodmgrl21PzKG0lhNSNLc/MPXPkmh/4qFbvw74VWyNBbrn38MaNhWMKcK36wEO86jiMbTBbrForg3EWX5317U4306WotQxzaFoLs@Ewmlv9AZcioceDMwoqsgqNsWsQubEBDD2uPn3QO3RtwH3sBCLYzDDGBC0rEqdo2fdYkQyyvKBDmSZ/fc7UXXS9ghEROI3iSRI1kEup94FklXOCNxmN@T5Nx2NYho1uIEa0f47v5Mzh/7HjV7tbWpCF8WG6cHY97@5EO1p2yJUik7zDtQ5kQllBS3Fq/FDkzeH@9izPmEC54c3LN0ES8ZugHhJmAo1VulvGPy0yOn5iBTszTyct1YXVp8MX) is the best I could get with a recursive method inside a lambda.

Comment: Hey, I found a way to do it by first defining the function. For example "int x = x + 5" is impossible because you haven't yet defined x, but "int x; x = x + 5" is possible (as long as it's a field, as those get predefined).

Answer (score 2):

### Bash, 21 bytes

```bash
s(){ seq $[++n];s;};s
```

```
1
1
2
1
2
3
…
```

[Run the 21B version on Try It Online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v1hDs1qhOLVQQSVaWzsv1rrYuta6@P9/AA)

This defines a function `s` that runs `seq NUMBER` where `NUMBER` starts at `1` and increments with each run, then it runs itself recursively. After the definition, we run `s`.

For the cost of 5B to specify `-s\`  (separator is a space character), it can be adapted to a one *answer* per line solution at 26 bytes:

```bash
s(){ seq -s\  $[++n];s;};s
```

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
…
```

[Run the 26B version on Try It Online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v1hDs1qhOLVQQbc4RkFBJVpbOy/Wuti61rr4/38A)

Comment: BTW, zsh can do this in 19B as `s(){seq $[++n];s};s`

Answer (score 2):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 24 bytes

```
range(range(infinite))+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/78oMS89VQNCZualZeZllqRqamob/v//L7@gJDM/r/i/bh4A) (requires the `-n` flag)

JQ is a stream-based language: every expression can return multiple values and when expressions are combined together the second one is flat-mapped over everything returned by the first. This makes it very easy to express infinite sequences.

`infinite` is a filter that ignores its input and returns a single infinite floating-point value.
`range(n)` is a filter that ignores its input and returns every positive integer smaller than `n`.
`+1` adds one to each value in the result.

By default if we run this program it will try to read from STDIN (because each filter needs to take an input, even if it is ignored). Therefore we pass the `-n` flag to tell the interpreter to pass a single `null` value as the input to the filter.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 14 bytes

```powershell
for(){1..++$i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f8/Lb9IQ7PaUE9PW1sls/b/fwA)

Will output the numbers of the sequence separated by a new line.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 36 bytes (including newline)

```
s=[1]
while 1:print(s);s+=[s[-1]+1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9g22jCWqzwjMydVwdCqoCgzr0SjWNO6WNs2ujha1zBW2zD2/38A)

Comment: My code seems to be exactly the same as the Python 3 solution above. I did not cheat (I haven't looked at the previous codes before I submitted my own answer); however, if this is against the guidelines I can delete my submission.

Comment: Duplicate answers are [permitted](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/92901). You might like to create a [TIO link](https://tio.run/) - there you can find a copy/paste template for formatting CGCC answers. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
{nɾṄ,
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyI1IiwiIiwie27JvuG5hCwiLCIiLCIiXQ==) The `5` flag makes the online interpreter time out after 5 seconds.

Explanation:

```
{      # Open a(n infinite) while loop
 n     # Get the loop variable's value
  ɾ    # Push the range from 1 to n
   Ṅ   # Join by spaces (ɾ creates a list)
    ,  # Print
```

Comment: You can just do `Þ∞K` to output an infinite list.

Comment: @Steffan Can you send me a link? It times out for me when I try to join the lists

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnuKInksiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Comment: @Steffan That doesn't join the lists, [This](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwiw57iiJ5L4bmEIiwiIiwiIl0=) times out, is what I meant.

Comment: The OP said that nested lists are fine. That times out because infinite strings are not a thing. You can add `f` if you don't like nested lists. You can also use the `S` flag to join by spaces, which will work on infinite lists

Answer (score 2):

## [Appleseed](https://github.com/dloscutoff/appleseed), 16 bytes

```lisp
(q(_(map 1to(1to
```

Anonymous function that can be called with no arguments and returns an infinite nested list `((1) (1 2) (1 2 3) ...)`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywoyEktTk1N@f9fIyU1TcFPo1AjXiM3sUDBsCRfA4ghwsUliUUligoaOYm5SSmJCvEKGgVFmXkgET9NIPgPAA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
(q           ; Anonymous function
 (_          ; that takes any number of arguments:
  (map 1to   ; Inclusive range from 1 to N for each N in
   (1to))))  ; numbers from 1 to infinity
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 23 bytes

```scala
Stream from 1 map(1 to)
```

[Try it online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/5NFOVBs8TZqGjdxuKURgSA)

An infinite `Stream` of `IntRange`s. Uses the sequence from the question.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>24</s> 33 bytes

Added 9 bytes to fix an error kindly pointed out by [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing).

```python
n=1
while 1:n+=1;print range(1,n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8/WkKs8IzMnVcHQKk/b1tC6oCgzr0ShKDEvPVXDUCdP8/9/AA)

Comment: This only prints each `n` once, rather than an infinite number of times. [This](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8/WkKs8IzMnVcHQKk/b1tC6oCgzr0ShKDEvPVXDUCdP8/9/AA) works however

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Oops, misread the question! T_T Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 11 bytes

```
_
}*M!&`_+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fK56rVstXUS0hXvv/fwA) Outputs in unary. Explanation: The first two lines cause the number of `_`s to increase on each pass, while the `` M!&`_+ `` generates all suffixes, which ensures that all integers get printed. The `}` causes the entire script to repeat indefinitely. The `*` causes the suffixes to be printed and discarded, since otherwise Retina does not output until the program terminates.

18 bytes for a traditional decimal output. Each integer is printed in turn, and then for each integer all of the previous integers are printed again, so the final sequence is 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3 ...

```
{`^
_
*(M!&`_+
%`_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@/OiGOK55LS8NXUS0hXptLNSH@/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

```
f!pS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P02xIPj/fwA)

### Explanation

```
f!pS
      : lambda T:
   S  :    range(1, T)
  p   :    print and return the range
 !    :    logical negate the range
f     : Find first natural number input to function that returns a truthy value
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 18 bytes

```
.say for [\,] 1..*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/1@vOLFSIS2/SCE6RidWwVBPT@v/fwA)

`[\,] 1..*` generates the list of prefixes of the sequence of naturals. `.say for` just prints them.

Comment: Disappointing that you can't drop the space after `for`, not because it's no longer recognizable as `for`, but because the compiler *recognizes that it is `for` and errors telling you you have to have whitespace*

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 47 bytes

```
var i=1
while true:
 for j in 1..i:echo j
 i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f@/LLFIIdPWkKs8IzMnVaGkqDTVikshLb9IIUshM0/BUE8v0yo1OSNfIYtLIVPb1vC/QmYaUL2tpVVSUWpi9n8A) The footer makes it finite so the output can be observed.

Note that Nim doesn't have bigints, so this works only in theory (in accordance with our rules).

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 56 bytes

```
(do((i 1(1+ i)))(())(dotimes(j i)(format t"~v^~a "j j)))
```

Nested loop solution using the `do` macro for the outer loop and the `dotimes` macro for the inner loop. `dotimes` starts with `0` so `format` includes a specifier that checks whether it's a `0`.

Answer (score 1):

## AWK, 33 bytes

An approach different from [@Noodle9](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215792/99944)'s, that luckly uses one less byte.

```
{for(;;a[++i])for(j in a)print j}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SMPaOjFaWzszVhPEyVLIzFNI1CwoyswrUciq/f@fCwA)

```
{
for(;;a[++i])  # by only stating the array[element], that element is created in the array.
               # all not assigned variables starts at 0.
               # at first, i++ would return 0, and increment 1 to i;
               # but ++i increments 1 to i, and then return its new value.
  for(j in a)  # for every element existing in the array,
    print j    # prints the element j.
}
```

---

## AWK, 37 bytes

Prints numbers in one line.

```
{for(;;a[++i])for(j in a)printf j FS}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SMPaOjFaWzszVhPEyVLIzFNI1CwoyswrSVPIUnALrv3/nwsA)

---

## AWK, 51 bytes

Prints numbers in a pyramid.

```
{for(;;a[++i])for(j in a)printf j+1 in a?j FS:j RS}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SMPaOjFaWzszVhPEyVLIzFNI1CwoyswrSVPI0jYE8@2zFNyCrbIUgoJr///nAgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) in unary, 16 bytes

```
s/^/1\n1/p;h;G;D
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WD9O3zAmz1C/wDrD2t3a5f9/AA)

Each unary natural is on its own line. Seems to increase logarithmically.

sed has two spaces: the default one is called the pattern space and is lost after processing the next of input; the other one is the hold space, which instead is retained throughout execution. Both start empty.

(sed cannot run without input, so this program is run with an empty line as input).

The idea is to have the largest number encountered so far on the first line, and then have the result of the previous iterations on the succeeding lines.

`s/^/1\n1/` replaces the beginning (symbolised with `^`, really just empty space) with `1` followed by a newline (`\n`) and another `1`. The `p` flag then prints the pattern space. The second `1` inserted increases the maximum number by 1, which was on the first line before the substitution, and now is on the second line.

`h` replaces the hold space with the contents of the pattern space, after which `G` appends the hold space to the pattern space, joining them by a newline. This is our method to retain the previous natural numbers encountered.

`D` deletes the first line (which in our case is always `1` thanks to the substitution made with the `s` command) and the newline after it. This effectively returns the largest number encountered so far back to the first line. Then `D` causes the program to be run from the beginning with what remains of the pattern space because the first line was not empty. Because the `s` command will always make sure the first line is not empty, the initial `1\n` effectively acts only for `D` to cause the program to loop indefinitely.

---

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 15 bytes

```
:;s/^/1/p;h;G;t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f/fyrpYP07fUL/AOsPa3brk/38A)

sed 4.2.2 allows empty labels, ridding the need for `1\n` and `D`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](https://tio.run/##RctLDsIgFIXhOau4cQSipHOsm6gz4wD7ysUWSLltYpquHfGROD3/d6xZzNGH1tnmkXAMfiKIZAhrsDmpwbheVc9I7aj2mtWDiREusLIw34eMfnbx2MBo0PGKJnT99QZGZNVxodnGvip9VJ7Wzk8cHQGWxcFqKfFcaD@TCvlLg@NCvIUtC22lPOG/cSt3sBNCb2lLLw), 76 chars

```java
void f(){for(int i=0,j;++i>0;out.println())for(j=0;j++<i;out.print(j+" "));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RctLDsIgFIXhOau4cQSipHOsm6gz4wD7ysUWSLltYpquHfGROD3/d6xZzNGH1tnmkXAMfiKIZAhrsDmpwbheVc9I7aj2mtWDiREusLIw34eMfnbx2MBo0PGKJnT99QZGZNVxodnGvip9VJ7Wzk8cHQGWxcFqKfFcaD@TCvlLg@NCvIUtC22lPOG/cSt3sBNCb2lLLw)

Output (unlimited):

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
. . .
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Chapel](http://chapel.cray.com/), 51 bytes

```
var i=1;while(i){for j in 1..i do writeln(j);i+=1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILEjN@f@/LLFIIdPW0Lo8IzMnVSNTszotv0ghSyEzT8FQTy9TISVfobwosyQ1J08jS9M6Uxuosvb/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Batch, 127 bytes

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "s=1"
set k=1
for /L %%a in (0,0,0) do (echo !s! &set /a k=k+1 &set "s=!s! !k!")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 20 bytes

```powershell
for(){' '+(1..++$i)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Py2/SEOzWl1BXVvDUE9PW1slU7P2/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 7 bytes

```
1`⁺řĐƥł
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/fMOFR466jM49MOLb0aNP//6YA)

Port of [caird coinheringaahing's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215769/116013).

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 9 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 7.41 bytes

```
[1+DR1+ZK
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYrow21XYIMtaO8IXyoMEwaAA)

13 chars for a better format: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZrow21XYIMtR3ji7OivCFiUCmYEgA)

##### Explanation

```python
[1+DR1+ZK  # TOS is initially 0
[          # while True:
 1+        #  increment TOS
   DR1+    #  push range(1, TOS+1)
       ZK  #  pop and print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
Þ∞K
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnuKInksiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

```
Þ∞ɾ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnuKInsm+IiwiIiwiIl0=)

##### Explanation

```python
Þ∞  # Push an infinite list of positive integers:   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]
  K # Get the prefixes of this list                 [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], ...]
  ɾ # Inclusive one-range of each:                  [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://python.org), 76 bytes

```python
def n():
 c=2
 while 1:
  yield from range(1,c)
  c+=1
for i in n():print(i)
```

Uses generators and `yield from` to chain infinite `range`s. You can call n directly for a generator.