# Verify the inequality!

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, random

Left in [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/20752#20752) for at least 3 days.

I want to verify if this inequality is true:

for \$n\geq4\$, if \$a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n\in R_+\cup\{0\}\$ and \$\sum_{i=1}^na_i=1\$, then \$a_1a_2+a_2a_3+a_3a_4+\dots+a_{n-1}a_n+a_na_1\leq\frac{1}{4}\$.

### Challenge

Write a piece of program which takes an integer `n` as input. It does the following:

1. Generate a random array `a` which consists of `n` non-negative reals. The sum of all elements should be 1.

> By saying *random*, I mean, every array satisfiying the requirements in 2 should have a non-zero probability of occurrence. It don't need to be uniform. See [this related post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17563/are-non-uniform-random-distributions-allowed).

2. Calculate `a[0]a[1]+a[1]a[2]+a[2]a[3]+...+a[n-2]a[n-1]+a[n-1]a[0]`.
3. Output the sum and the array `a`.

> For I/O forms see [this post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).

### Rules

(Sorry for the late edit...) All numbers should be rounded to **at least** \$10^{-4}\$.

Standard [loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) should be forbidden.

### Example

The following code is an ungolfed Python code for this challenge, using library `numpy`. (For discussion about using libraries, see [This Link](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188/using-libraries-in-solutions).)

```python
import numpy as np


def inequality(n):
    if n < 4:
       raise Exception
    a = np.random.rand(n)
    sum_a = 0
    for i in range(n):
        sum_a += a[i]
    for i in range(n):
        a[i] /= sum_a
    sum_prod = 0
    for i in range(n):
       sum_prod += a[i % n] * a[(i + 1) % n]
    print(a)
    return sum_prod, a
```

### Tip

You could assume that input `n` is a positive integer greater than 3.

---

Your score is the *bytes* in your code. The one with the least score wins.

Comment: A test code can be found [here](https://tio.run/##XY3LasMwEEX3/oohULCaYDQzGj0C/pKQhWjtxuDaRrEX/npXSummIJB07pk7y74@5omPI0ILt36c41p3Cvo5QQfDlM@yrbVqnss4rPXpAid1r5Y0TPnz3L5h7mGftwQxpbhfIQuZ1lGpqqQt6KpUDaUqxemrq8duKvG1gmLCuYV4G@7wnq96gDOggjf4lf4vWh8dLGn@3D7Wv03qOHRDXrOzTAZREwe0F9CNCd6RliCGDFvPhXmLYkkHi9qagFiY9sQusMue5Ni9hoW982QISeeSl4fBaqI8Z9GgYW0KDBwCErI4h5JfhbGIoBXGIN4ZMeYH).

Comment: Would just like to note that, all of the answers are going to be generating and summing rationals, leaving almost all reals untested

Comment: @Cruncher Hard for computers to manipulate irrationals... will edit to noticeall numbers can be rounded to at least 4 digits?

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly my point. Not saying it's an issue for the coding challenge, just being pedantic. Maybe the inequality trying to prove should be for Q+ and not R+

Answer (score 4):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 21 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
(+/⊢×1∘⌽)⎕←(⊢÷+/)?⎕⍴0
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=09DWf9S16PB0w0cdMx717NV81Df1UdsEDZDYdm19TXsQv3eLAQA&f=AwA&i=S@My5eJK4zI0AAA&r=tio&l=apl-dyalog&m=tradfn&n=f)

A tradfn submission which prints the list and returns the sum.

```
                  ⎕⍴0 ⍝ create a vector with input-many 0's
                 ?    ⍝ for each 0, get a random number between 0 and 1
            ⊢÷        ⍝ divide each number by
              +/      ⍝ the sum of all numbers
         ⎕←           ⍝ print the resulting vector
   ⊢×                 ⍝ multiply the vector element-wise
     1∘⌽              ⍝ with the vector rotated to the left by 1
 +/                   ⍝ take the sum of all products
```

If appending the sum to the list is fine as output, this could be 20 bytes: [`x,+/x×1⌽x←(⊢÷+/)?⎕⍴0`](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=q9DR1q84PN3wUc/eikdtEzQedS06vF1bX9P@Ud/UR71bDAA&f=AwA&i=S@My5eJK4zI0AAA&r=tio&l=apl-dyalog&m=tradfn&n=f)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>49</s> 45 bytes

```r
a=rexp(scan());a=a/sum(a);a;a%*%c(a[-1],a[1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9G2KLWiQKM4OTFPQ1PTOtE2Ub@4NFcjEci0TlTVUk3WSIzWNYzVSYw2jNX8b/ofAA)

-4 bytes by Robin Ryder

Comment: [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9G2KLWiQKM4OTFPQ1PTOtE2Ub@4NFcjEci0TlTVUk3WSIzWNYzVSYw2jNX8b/ofAA "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>89</s>  88 bytes

Returns `[ array, sum ]`.

```javascript
f=(n,a=[],t=s=0)=>n?f(n-1,[...a,v=Math.random()],t+v):[a.map(k=>(s+=v/t*(v=k),v/t)),s/t]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vco9DoMwDEDhvSexizEgdapkeoKeIGKwgPQHcBCJcv2UtdvTp/fVrHE8PnuqLUxzKV7ASMUNlCRKi9Lbw4PVHTlmVsry1PTmQ20KG@C5VRnvTnnTHRbpIVaSm3SFLAvSWYgUmzSUMVgM68xreIGHG@LlX7oWsfwA)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                      // f is a recursive function taking:
  n,                       //   n = input
  a = [],                  //   a[] = array
  t =                      //   t = sum of non-normalized values
  s = 0                    //   s = sum of a[i] * a[(i + 1) mod n] / t
) =>                       //
n ?                        // if n is not equal to 0:
  f(                       //   do a recursive call:
    n - 1,                 //     decrement n
    [ ...a,                //     pass a new array with all previous elements of a[]
      v = Math.random() ], //     followed by a new random value v in [0,1)
    t + v                  //     add v to t
  )                        //   end of recursive call
:                          // else:
  [                        //   build the answer array:
    a.map(k =>             //     for each value k in a[]:
      ( s +=               //       add to s:
          v / t            //         the previous normalized value v / t,
          * (v = k),       //         multiplied by k (and update v to k)
        v / t              //       yield the normalized value
      )                    //
    ),                     //     end of map()
    s / t                  //     also return the normalized sum
  ]                        //   end of answer array
```

Comment: The result seems wrong. Notice that your sum of products should be `s / t / t`, because `s` is a quadratic expression.

Comment: @SketchySketch `s` is the sum of `a[i-1] / t * a[i]`, so we only need to divide once by `t` at the end of the process.

Comment: Oh sorry, missed that.

Comment: @SketchySketch [Here](https://tio.run/##ZY3BasMwEETv@YolEFjFG8W@psj9gvjQQi/Gh8WWUze2ZCRZ0K931QRKm552dvbNzgdH9q0b5nAwttPr2is0xKpuKCivcqFK89yjORRUSymZojpzeJeOTWcnFAnLojjVLCee8apK9JmKx7DHqK6CkhKC/DE0awUKivxpUwM7x58EfpmgSWaPldi01ng7ajnaC97uf63ta4JtD5HHRfvTlu5PpNPd0mrEmaAVoEqYIUvqIfyiw@KM7m6V3@E0H5A37YZ@@IX8@x8Jhp@KCPs7UeOQ1kLADqqGIBdi/QI) is some extra code to double-check the result.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 46 bytes

```
n->(a=rand(n);a/=sum(a))=>a[2:end]'*a[1:end-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvs/T9dOI9G2KDEvRSNP0zpR37a4NFcjUVPT1i4x2sgqNS8lVl0rMdoQxNI1jP1fUJSZV5KTp5GmYaqp@R8A)

returns `array => sum`

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 42 bytes

```
{##2,#}&@@#.#|#&[#/Tr@#&@RandomReal[1,#]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7v1pZ2UhHuVbNwUFZT7lGWS1aWT@kyEFZzSEoMS8lPzcoNTEn2lBHOTZW7b9LfnRAUWZeSXSmrl2aQ2asTnWmjomOWa2OoUHsfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>17</s> <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 17 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
₄Ý.rI£DO/ÐÀ*O‚
```

Outputs as a pair `[array, sum]`.

-2 bytes thanks to *@Neil*.
-1 byte by changing two explicit prints with enclose/overlap builtins `=Ćü*O,` to something similar as [my MathGolf answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219166/52210) with pair and implicit print `ÐÀ*O‚`
+2 bytes so duplicated items are possible and +1 byte to maximize the amount of floats possible

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9vc2FiaWX//@KChMOdSdC4LnJJwqNETy/DkMOAKk/igJr//zEw) (but uses `[0,1000]` instead of `[0,9876543210]` to speed things up a bit).

**Explanation:**

```python
žmÝ               # Push a list in the range [0,9876543210]
   Iи             # Repeat it the input amount of times
                  # (so we can potentially get duplicated items)
     .r           # Randomly shuffle this list
       I£         # Only leave the first input amount of values
         D        # Duplicate this list
          O       # Sum them together
           /      # Divide all values by this sum
                  # (so we now have a list of random values summing to 1)
            Ð     # Triplicate this list
             À    # Rotate the top copy once towards the left
              *   # Multiply the top two lists position-wise together
               O  # Sum this list
                ‚ # Pair the list together with this sum
                  # (after which this pair is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: I don't think you have to divide the list by 1000, since you're dividing all values by their sum anyway.

Comment: @Neil Ah of course. Thanks! :)

Comment: Doesn't this have a zero probability of outputting a list with any equal elements? (...and also other lists which should have non-zero probability - or is 1000 big enough to produce all floats somehow?) Also what happens when `n>1001`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan You're right about the first part, since I shuffle a list with unique values. I can fix that in two bytes by repeating the list the input amount of times before shuffling if necessary (is it necessary?). 05AB1E doesn't have any float random builtins, which is why I use this approach in the first place. If you look at my initial 17-byte version you can see I had `₄Ý₄/` and also added a comment about having more decimal digits by increasing that to let's say \$10^6\$ by adding two bytes.

Comment: @JonathanAllan As for whether `1000` is big enough to produce all floats, I doubt it.. And increasing it to let's say `5000` should hold similar results I'm pretty sure, and the higher you go, the more unique floats become available I guess. The `DO/` makes sure the floats will sum to 1. Do we know how accurate floats have to be for "_By saying random, I mean, every array satisfying the requirements in 2 should have a non-zero probability of occurrence._" to be true?

Comment: If the output list contains floats I would think that all lists of floats in `[0,1)` that can sum to `1` need to be possible.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Added 2 bytes to allowed for duplicated items and 1 byte to up the range to `[0,9876543210]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>30</sup> <sup>27</sup> 25 bytes

<sup>-2 to thanks to [ovs's rotate idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219163/15469)</sup>

```
[:(;1#.]*1|.])@(%+/)?@$&0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlGGumaGWprs6lpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o600rA2V9WK1DGv0YjUdNFS19TXtHVTUDP5rcvk56SlA5Y209GNidar1kFVwcaUmZ@QrpCmY/AcA)

- `$&0` Duplicate 0 "input" times.
- `?@` And "roll" for each (`?0` produces a random number between 0 and 1).
- `[:...(%+/)` Divide each by sum of all.
- `(;1#.]*1|.])` To that boxed list append `;` the sum of `1#.` the list `]` times `*` the list rotated once to the left `1|.]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
ＦＮ⊞υ‽φ≧∕Συυ⊞υΣＥυ×ι§υ⊕κＩ⮌υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzBCsIwEETvfkWOG4hQwZunopceLFL9gdis7WKzLUm2@PcxFZzTMDNv@tGGfrZTzq85KGh4kdSKf2IArdVN4ghiVGfZzR4OVVVpfdpd7VLHSAN3NIwJLrSSQ6Pu4kG0UVImf3LLynyzD/IYgYyqU8MOP1vWcB/QIyd08NY/FTYQJzjbmKDDFUPEcluKnI95v05f) Like the 05AB1E answer, I generate `n` random numbers between `0` and `999`, then scale them so their sum is 1. A larger range could be obtained at the cost of one or two bytes. Also, it's unclear whether the sum has to be first; printing it last would save two bytes. Explanation:

```
ＦＮ
```

Repeat `n` times...

```
⊞υ‽φ
```

... push a random integer to the predefined empty list.

```
≧∕Συυ
```

Divide the list by its sum.

```
⊞υΣＥυ×ι§υ⊕κ
```

Multiply each element by its neighbour and push the sum to the list.

```
Ｉ⮌υ
```

Print the list in reverse so that the sum is first.

Comment: Given that OP linked to standard IO rules, I took that mean either order was ok.

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
Äƒ]_Σ/∙╫m*Σ
```

Outputs the array and sum concatenated to one another.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9tYXRoZ29sZv//w4TGkl1fzqMv4oiZ4pWrbSrOo///NAo2CjEw)

**Explanation:**

```python
Ä            # Loop the (implicit) input amount of times,
             # using a single character as inner code-block:
 ƒ           #  Push a random float in the range [0,1]
  ]          # Wrap all values on the stack into a list
   _         # Duplicate this list
    Σ        # Take the sum of it
     /       # Divide all values in the list by this sum
             # (so we now have a list of random values summing to 1)
      ∙      # Triplicate this list
       ╫     # Rotate the top copy once towards the left
        m*   # Multiply the top two lists position-wise together
          Σ  # Take the sum of that list
             # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>124</s></sup> 121 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)!!!
Saved 3 bytes thanks to [Danis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99104/danis)!!!

```python
def f(n):l=[random()for i in[0]*n];l=[e/sum(l)for e in l];return l,sum(a*b for a,b in zip(l,l[1:]+l))
from random import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JczBCgIhEIDhe08xxxlbqKjTLj2JeHBZJUFHmdzD9vKmdfvhg78c9ZX53trmPHhkmuNTi@UtJySfBQIE1lej2Cxd3OW9J4w/cV0gmkVc3aXXNMiqFQbaaR38CQXjFPVtNudIdPKSE/z3EFLJUlUrErii8vggal8)

Comment: using def instead of lambda would be a little shorter

Comment: https://tio.run/##JczBCgIhEIDhe08xxxlbqKjTLj2JeHBZJUFHmdzD9vKmdfvhg78c9ZX53trmPHhkmuNTi@UtJySfBQIE1lej2Cxd3OW9J4w/cV0gmkVc3aXXNMiqFQbaaR38CQXjFPVtNudIdPKSE/z3EFLJUlUrErii8vggal8

Comment: @Danis Nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/), 75 bytes

```python
from numpy import*
def f(n):x=random.rand(n);x/=sum(x);return x,x@roll(x,1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcgxCoAwDADA3Vd0TEQU0UkR/IqgRcEkJbaQvr7qdHAhx1N4KMWrkONEIbuLgmisq/3wzgPjZItuvAu1P1/M1i1PIjCc9YhJ2Vljq8p9gzU9lqAXR6g9jIjlBQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 13 bytes

```
l&rts/ttlYS*s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P0etqKRYv6QkJzJYq/j/fxMA)

**Explanation**

```
             % Implicitly retrieve input (N) as an integer
l            % Push the literal 1 to the stack
&r           % Create an N x 1 array of random floats
t            % Duplicate this array
s            % Sum the elements of this array
/            % And perform element-wise division of the original array by this sum
             % to get the array, A
tt           % Duplicate A (twice)
lYS          % Circularly shift A by 1 element
*            % Perform element-wise multiplication with A
s            % Compute the sum
             % Implicitly display A and the sum of the products
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <sup><s>83 82 72</s></sup> 71 bytes

```ruby
->n{k=(1..n).map{rand};p=k[~-s=0]/z=k.sum;[k.map{|x|s+=p*x/z;p=x/z},s]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOttWw1BPL09TLzexoLooMS@l1rrANju6TrfY1iBWv8o2W6@4NNc6OhssX1NRU6xtW6BVoV8FVAUka3WKY2v/FyikRZvG/gcA)

-4,-1,-6 from ASCII-only!

-4, shortening it further.

-1 more byte from ASCII-only.

Comment: Tried it online; the sum of your array doesn't seem to be 1.

Comment: @SketchySketch fixed it

Comment: why the `*1.0`?

Comment: @ASCII-only Added it due to paranoia and forgot about it

Comment: [82](https://tio.run/##HclLCoAgEADQq7S0sOkDrcIuIhJjJcHQFEWLUM9u1PLxzts@yalUDuxJiQaAc9jw8CfyHHtNin4GDlwRXPcWpS5Ikq6NgQWndZx2vkSbf@cDShuwsNHEdGROdya9)

Comment: [74?](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOttWw1BPL09TLzexoLooMS@l1rrANjta1zBWX6PKNluvuDRX07rY1sA6OhuspCavpljbtkArT78KqBBI1uoUx9b@L1BIizaN/Q8A)

Comment: @ASCII-only yep! For some reason using `$.` in place of `s` gives 0 as the sum.

Comment: i'm guessing `$.` is read only

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215803/80214 seems to work here

Comment: [71](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOttWw1BPL09TLzexoLooMS@l1rrANju6TrfY1iBWv8o2W6@4NNc6OhssX1NRU6xtW6BVoV8FVAUka3WKY2v/FyikRZvG/gcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>No built-in for random floats, so half the code is that!</sup>

```
2ṗ⁹XHCḅ.)÷S$µṙ1ḋƊ,
```

A monadic Link accepting an integer, `n`, which yields a list containing a non-negative float (the sum of products) and the generated list of non-negative floats of length `n` which sums to `1`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//MuG5lzlYSEPhuIUuKcO3UyTCteG5mTHhuIvGiiz///80)** (Note that `⁹` (\$256\$) has been replaced with `9` (\$9\$) for speed - generating all \$2^{256}\$ lists of bits would take a while. Using a number as big as \$256\$ is not necessary, it's just terse.)

#### How?

(Bug fixed above, will update this section later.)

Note: Uses 256 random bits to generate a random float in \$[0,1]\$.

```
2ṗ⁹XHCḅ.)µ÷Sṙ1ḋƊ, - Link: n
         )        - for each:
2                 -   2
  ⁹               -   256
 ṗ                -   (256) Cartesian product (2 implicitly -> [1,2])
   X              -   pick one at random        e.g.  [1,2,2,1, ... ,1,2]
    H             -   halve                           [0.5,1,1,0.5, ... ,0.5,1]
     C            -   complement                      [0.5,0,0,0.5, ... ,0.5,0]
       .          -   a half                          0.5
      ḅ           -   convert (list) from base (0.5)  a float in [0,1]
         µ        - start a new monadic chain         (call that x)
           S      - sum                               sum(x)
          ÷       - divide                            normalised(x)
               Ɗ  - last three links as a monad:      (call that Y=[y1,y2,...,yn])
                  -   one                             1
            ṙ     -   rotate left by (1)              [y2,...,yn,y1]
              ḋ   -   dot product (with Y)            y1.y2+y2.y3+...+yn.y1
                , - pair                              [y1.y2+y2.y3+...+yn.y1, Y]
```

Comment: Tried it online; the sum of your output array isn't 1.

Comment: Oops, [this](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//MuG5lzlYSEPhuIUuKcO3UyTCteG5mTHhuIvGiiz///80) should fix it. Will update the post later. Thanks for notifying!